# Python: send a mail in html with sendmail

Tags: python, sendmail

Can someone tell me how to send a mail in a HTML format with sendmail in python?

I would like to send this:

```
<pre>some code</pre>
```

Python version is 2.4.3 and can't be updated.

Comment: if smtp is a viable solution you could check http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-in-python ?

Comment: not actualy a duplicate since OP is trying to use sendmail and smtp might not be a viable solution .

Comment: smtp is not an option here :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# assemble the mail content
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
message = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
message.add_header('Subject', 'subject goes here')
# add a few more add_header calls here for things like "To", "Cc", "From"
message.attach(MIMEText('some code')) # plain text alternative
message.attach(MIMEText('<html><pre>some code</pre></html>', # html content
                        'html'))

# pipe the mail to sendmail
sendmail = os.popen('sendmail recipient@example.org', 'w')
sendmail.write(message.as_string())
if sendmail.close() is not None:
   print 'error: failed to send mail :-('
```

Answer (score 1):

You may check the code of webpy micro-framework for various methods of sending email, including the sendmail: https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/utils.py#L1415

Answer (score 0):

Simply give the HTML code in the message and also mention the mime version and content as text/html. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm

Answer (score 0):

I find a easy way to do this:

When I run my script, I write my output in a file (mail.txt), then at the end, I just call:

```
os.popen('cat mail.txt | sendmail -t')
```

mail.txt content:

```
To: my.mail@gmail.com
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="123"
Subject: My subject

This is a MIME-encapsulated message

--123
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML E-mail</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <pre>Some code</pre>
   </body>
</html>
```

Maybe is not the best way to do this, but works fine for me...