# How to send HTML email usind sendmail command from Python

Tags: python, sendmail

I have the next code:

```
def send_email(self, alert_emails, subj, msg):
  global alert_from

  p = os.popen("/usr/sbin/sendmail -t" , 'w')
  p.write("To: %s\n" % (','.join(alert_emails),))
  p.write("From: %s\n" % (alert_from,))
  p.write("Subject: %s\n\n" % (subj,))
  p.write(msg)
  return p.close()
```

It sends plain text messages. How can I change it to send HTML messages instead?

Thanks

Comment: Already answered:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Content-Type: text/html` header.  And use `smtplib` to send emails.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use `sendmail` directly? Python has libraries for this sort of thing. Use the [`email`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html) module to create your mail, and [`smtplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) to send it.

Plus there's no need to use a `global` statement unless you're modifying the global variable inside your function, which you're not.

Comment: not sure why, but when I use smtplib all emails go to spam. I don't know why, but sendmail -t works ok with plaintext messages. I know it's lame :) may be you're right and I have to find why all emails go to spam using smtplib...