# Python :How to send Html in mail in Python?

Tags: python, smtp

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "my@email.com"
you = "xyz@gmail.com"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you wanted:\nhttp://www.python.org"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <a href="http://google.com/">Launch Now</a>
     <br/>
     <br/>
         - Google
         <br/>
         <br/>
         <a href="http://google.com/">Contact</a> Support
 </body>
</html>
"""

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

I am getting only the HTML in my mail not the text
I used this code from here [Sending HTML email using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-in-python)

Comment: Are you sure?  Have you looked at the source of the email?  You could add a line just before sending it, `print(msg.as_string())`, and you should see both parts in the output.

Comment: please put you = "xyz@gmail.com" your email id here and check , the text part is not coming

Comment: I added the debugging string... it's there.  What version of Python are you using?  And have you looked at the source of the email?  What email client are you using?

Comment: BTW, I was trying this with Python 2.6.