# Corrupted HTML when sent by email

Tags: python, html, mime

When I use python's mime utility to send HTML emails. I receive corrupted HTML emails as explained below. When I send UTF-8 HTML emails, the problem seams to go away.

Note that I am only sending ascii characters, no UTF-8 characters at all.

I used this template from [Sending HTML email using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python) :

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "my@email.com"
you = "your@email.com"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Link"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = "Hi!\nHow are you?\nHere is the link you wanted:\nhttp://www.python.org"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <table cellpadding="3">
      <tbody>
      <tr style="background-color:#d4d4d4">
      <td>One</td>
      <td>Two</td>
      <td>Three</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

I do receive an email, but sometimes this line:

```
'<tr style="background-color:#d4d4d4">'
```

will be replaced by:

```
&lt;tr style=&quot;background-color:#d4d4d4&quot;&gt
```

causing the resulting html to be erroneous.

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm trying to fix the same issue. What mail client(s) were you using to receive the emails?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not!

Answer (score -1):

style="background-color:#d4d4d4">
Double check that you are escaping your quotes properly.  eg: maybe use single quote here.

Comment: If it was an escape problem, it would be systematic and not random.