# How to use Python and Mailchimp to send an email?

Tags: python, email, mailchimp

I have been reading a lot on the Internet to know how I can use Python to send emails using mailchimp API. It seems that the website is so complected and doesn't have any example.

Please, could you guide me to any example including a Python use?

#### What I tried so far:

- I installed the library from pip using: 
  `pip install mailchimp`;
- I have created the campain;
- I have created the lists;

But yet, I couldn't know how to send the emails programmatically.

Comment: What about this? https://github.com/mailchimp/mcapi2-python-examples

Comment: @mrcrgl I have already checked that link and the read me of it. there is no code there to send email, you can check

Comment: If you just want to send email and not do mailing lists, Mandrill is a spin off company from Mailchimp: http://mandrill.com/ - they give you SMTP server credentials and after that you can follow in Python email sending tutorial using those credentials.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa may you show me the link for the tutorial please?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python - just configure `smtplib.SMTP()` with your external SMTP server credentials.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to trigger a campaign see:

https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/campaigns/send.php

The typical module `mailchimp` at pypi supports it as followed.

```
from mailchimp import Mailchimp
mailchimp = Mailchimp(api_key)
mailchimp.campaigns.send(campaign_id)
```

Sourcecode at: https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mailchimp-api-python/src/32ed2394d6b49d7551089484221fa3ee019bee37/mailchimp.py?at=master

Hope it helps.

Cheers,
mrcrgl

Comment: That is helpful really, but how can i got the `api_key`? plus, i have already added a campaign but i didn't receive any `campaing-id`

Comment: do you mean by `api_key` the `client_secret` key in the dashbaord when you create an app? or the `client_id` ?

Comment: I imported `mailchimp` and when I tried your first code, i got `NameError: name 'Mailchimp' is not defined`

Comment: You need to import it `from mailchimp import Mailchimp`. I'm not a customer of mailchimp, so, please research and try yourself. I'll paste the current code of mailchimp client sdk into my answer, there you see the methods