# SMTP sending mail failure

Tags: python, email, sendmail

I've got a simple SMTP mailing example from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm) and my modified it. My code is:

```
import smtplib
sender = 'igor.savinkin@gmail.com'
receivers = ['igor.savinkin@gmail.com']
message = """From: From Igor <igor.savinkin@gmail.com>
To: To Igor Savinkin <igor.savinkin@gmail.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test
This is a test e-mail message from SMTP python.
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email to " + receivers.__str__()
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

Output is:

> Successfully sent email to ['igor.savinkin@gmail.com']

Yet, in actuality I find no mails like these in my inbox. The spam folder is checked too!
What's wrong? I use rhc (OpenShift) platform.

Comment: Its working for me in normal linux server

Comment: As you are using a more restricted environment(openshift), maybe smtp port 25 is blocked. Check iptables.

Comment: I used `except Exception,e:` and printed it .which showed `[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` mine is a windows machine

Comment: @duck, where/how can I *Check iptables*?

Comment: I've done more search and succeded in sending mail thru the [Gmail help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26369282/1230477)

Answer (score 2):

You send your mail to a local SMTP server (`smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')`). IMHO it accepts it (request is syntactically correct) but is then not allowed (or not configured) to forward it to gmail. I'm not using OpenShift so I do not know how SMTP is configured there.

You should control how the local SMTP server is configured.

Comment: most likely it's the case