# Python mail inserts space every 171 characters

Tags: python, email, whitespace

I am trying to write a python script to send an email that uses html formatting and involves a lot of non-breaking spaces. However, when I run it, some of the &nbsp strings are interrupted by spaces that occur every 171 characters, as can be seen by this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import smtplib
import socket
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

emails = ["my@email.com"]
sender = "test@{0}".format(socket.gethostname())

message = "<html><head></head><body>"
for i in range(20):
        message += "&nbsp;" * 50
        message += "<br/>"
message += "</body>"
message = MIMEText(message, "html")
message["Subject"] = "Test"
message["From"] = sender
message["To"] = ", ".join(emails)
mailer = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
mailer.sendmail(sender, emails, message.as_string())
mailer.quit()
```

The example should produce a blank email that consists of only spaces, but it ends up looking something like this:

```
         &nbsp ;                                    


                       &nb sp;                      


                                     & nbsp;        






             &nbs p;                                


                           &n bsp;
```

Edit: In case it is important, I am running Ubuntu 15.04 with Postfix for the smtp client, and using python2.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can replicate this in a way but my line breaks come every 999 characters. RFC 821 says maximum length of a line is 1000 characters including the line break so that's probably why.

This post gives a different way to send a html email in python, and i believe the mime type "multipart/alternative" is the correct way. 
[Sending HTML email using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python)

Comment: That was the problem, so it's trivial to just add a \n after every <br/> to cause this issue to disappear.

Comment: But the \n shows up in the email (at least as rendered in Outlook). How can you insert the line break without it being seen by the recipient as a \n?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer of [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail), a package that tries to make it easy to send emails.

You can use the following code:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('me@gmail.com', 'mypassword')

for i in range(20):
    message += "&nbsp;" * 50
    message += "<br/>"

yag.send(contents = message)
```

Note that by default it will send a HTML message, and that it also adds automatically the alternative part for non HTML browsers.

Also, note that omitting the `subject` will leave an empty subject, and without a `to` argument it will send it to self.

Furthermore, note that if you set yagmail up correctly, you can just login using `yag.SMTP()`, without having to have username & password in the script (while still being secure). Omitting the password will prompt a `getpass`.

Adding an attachment is as simple as pointing to a local file, e.g.:

```
yag.send(contents = [message, 'previously a lot of whitespace', '/local/path/file.zip']
```

Awesome isn't it? Thanks for the allowing me to show a nice use case for yagmail :)

If you have any feature requests, issues or ideas please let me know at [github](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail).

Comment: This package looks great, but unfortunately I can't pull in any external dependencies for my script. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Programman That's too bad. I hope you'll once have the opportunity to utilize it :)