# Why HTML convert python output '<' = &lt, '>' = &gt?

Tags: python, html, outlook

I created a script who send mail whith a specific output took from a server.
I splited this output and each element I sent it to a html cell.
I also created a header for the table what is looks like that:

```
def get_html_table_header(*column_names):
    header_string = '<tr width=79 style="background:#3366FF;height:23.25pt;font-size:8.0pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:white;font-weight:bold;" >'
    for column in column_names:
        if column is not None:
            header_string += '<td>' + column + '</td>'

    header_string += '</tr>'
    return header_string 

def get_concrete_html_table_header():
    return get_html_table_header('Num. Row','Cell1','Cell2','Cell3','Comment (enter your feedback below)','Cell4','Cell5','Cell6','Cell7','Cell8','Cell9','Cell10')
```

When I print the result of this function in linux konsole, it looks like that:

```
<tr width=79 style="background:#3366FF;height:23.25pt;font-size:8.0pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:white;font-weight:bold;" ><td>Num. Row</td><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td><td>Cell3</td><td>Comment (enter your feedback below)</td><td>Cell4</td><td>Cell5</td><td>Cell6</td><td>Cell7</td><td>Cell8</td><td>Cell9</td><td>Cell10</td></tr>
```

When I receive the email, source looks like that:

```
<tr width="79" style="background:#3366FF;height:23.25pt;font-size:8.0pt;font-family:Arial,sans-serif;color:white;font-weight:bold;"><td>Num. Row</td><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td><td>Cell3</td><td>Comment (enter your feedback below)</td><td>Cell4</td><td>Cell5</td><td>Cell6</td><td>Cell7</td><td>Cell8</td><td>Cell9</td>&lt; td&gt;Cell10</td></tr>
```

To build email body I`m using function:

```
def build_email_body(CRs_list):
    global criterial_number

    if 0 == len(CRs_list):
        return None

    email_body = ''
    email_body += '<html><head><title>My Title</title></head><body>'
    email_body += '<p align="center"><font color="#176b54" size="+2"><b>Some info</b></font></p>'
    email_body += '<p align="center"><font color="#176b54" size="+1">Another info</font></p>'
    email_body += '<table align="center" BORDER=1 CELLSPACING=2 CELLPADDING=2 COLS=3 WIDTH="100%">'
    email_body += get_concrete_html_table_header()

    for CR in CRs_list:
         email_body +=  get_html_table_row()#create row for every output received(11 cells for every output, according with the header)

    email_body += '</table>'

    email_body += '</table><br><p align="left"><font color="#176b54" size="+1"><b>=> This is an automatic generated email via script<br>'
    email_body += '<br><br>Have a nice day!</b></font></p><br></body></html>'

    return email_body
```

To send email I`m using function:

```
def send_email(body, recipients, subject, file):

    #inform just sender
    if None == body:
        body = "WARNING -> NO entries retrieved after 5 retries<br>CRAU output:<br>" + dct_newCRs_output + "<br>" + duration
        #override recipients to not set junk info
        recipients = sender

    email = Email(SMTP_SERVER, SENDER, recipients, _CC, subject, body, 'html', file)
    email.send()
```

send() is imported from class Email:

```
import os, smtplib
from email import encoders
from email.mime.audio import MIMEAudio
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import mimetypes

class Email:
    __config = {}
    def __init__(self, smtp_server, sender, recipients, cc, subject, body, body_type, attachments=None):
        self.__config = {'smtp_server': smtp_server,
            'sender': sender,
            'recipients': recipients,
            'cc': cc,
            'subject': subject,
            'body':body,
            'body_type':body_type,  #plain|html
            'attachments':attachments #list of files
        }       

    def getSmtpServer(self):
        return self.__config.get('smtp_server')
    def getSender(self):
        return self.__config.get('sender')
    def getRecipients(self):
        return self.__config.get('recipients')
    def getCc(self):
        return self.__config.get('cc')
    def getSubject(self):
        return self.__config.get('subject')
    def getBody(self):
        return self.__config.get('body')
    def getBodyType(self):
        return self.__config.get('body_type')
    def getAttachments(self):
        return self.__config.get('attachments')



    def setSmtpServer(self, host):
        self.__config['smtp_server'] = smtp_server
        return self
    def setSender(self, sender):
        self.__config['sender'] = sender
        return self
    def setRecipients(self, recipients):
        self.__config['recipients'] = recipients
        return self
    def setCc(self, cc):
        self.__config['cc'] = cc
        return self
    def setSubject(self, subject):
        self.__config['subject'] = subject
        return self
    def setBody(self, body):
        self.__config['body'] = body
        return selfMIMEMultipart
    def setBodyType(self, body_type):
        self.__config['body_type'] = body_type
        return self
    def setAttachments(self, attachments):
        self.__config['attachments'] = attachments
        return self

    def attachFilesToEmail(self, attachments, msg):
        if None == attachments:
            tmpmsg = msg
            msg = MIMEMultipart()
            msg.attach(tmpmsg)
        if None != attachments:
            for fname in attachments:
                if not os.path.exists(fname):
                    print "File '%s' does not exist.  Not attaching to email." % fname
                    continue
                if not os.path.isfile(fname):
                    print "Attachment '%s' is not a file.  Not attaching to email." % fname
                    continue
                # Guess at encoding type
                ctype, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(fname)
                if ctype is None or encoding is not None:
                    # No guess could be made so use a binary type.
                    ctype = 'application/octet-stream'
                maintype, subtype = ctype.split('/', 1)
                if maintype == 'text':
                    fp = open(fname)
                    attach = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
                    fp.close()
                elif maintype == 'image':
                    fp = open(fname, 'rb')
                    attach = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
                    fp.close()
                elif maintype == 'audio':
                    fp = open(fname, 'rb')
                    attach = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=subtype)
                    fp.close()
                else:
                    fp = open(fname, 'rb')
                    attach = MIMEBase(maintype, subtype)
                    attach.set_payload(fp.read())
                    fp.close()
                    # Encode the payload using Base64
                    encoders.encode_base64(attach)
                # Set the filename parameter
                filename = os.path.basename(fname)
                attach.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
                msg.attach(attach)

    def send(self):
        # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = self.getSubject()
        msg['From'] = self.getSender()
        msg['To'] = self.getRecipients()
        msg['CC'] = self.getCc()

        # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
        #part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
        #part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
        part = MIMEText(self.getBody(), self.getBodyType())

        # Attach parts into message container.
        # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
        # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
        msg.attach(part)

        # Add attachments, if any
        self.attachFilesToEmail(self.getAttachments(), msg)

        # Send the message via local SMTP server.
        s = smtplib.SMTP(self.getSmtpServer())
        # sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
        # and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
        s.sendmail(self.getSender(), (self.getRecipients() + self.getCc()).split(","), msg.as_string())
        s.quit()
```

I hope is enough information.
Can someone explain to me, why is happening this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please state how you are sending the mail. Maybe the mistake happens there.

Comment: As a sidenote, you should avoid concatenating strings in a loop like this. You should build a list, and `''.join()` it when you're done.

Comment: @spectras why? just curious.

Comment: It avoids building all the intermediate strings. Granted, recent versions of CPython now optimize this pretty well, but it's not true for older versions, or for other python implementations such as pypy.

Comment: @RouvenB. I edited my question! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct, the problem is elsewhere.

`&lt;` is what you get when you add `<` as text to a HTML document (since `<` means "start new element", you need to escape this character in plain text).

The interesting part here is why does it happen only once in the whole string. If all the `<` had been replaced, my guess would be that you accidentally added the table as text to the HTML body of the mail.

Maybe the space in `&lt; td&gt;` is a clue: Mails shouldn't have more than 72 characters per line. So maybe some mail server wraps the HTML? Outlook is known to mess a lot with the mails it receives.

Try to send the HTML code as multipart attachment. See [Sending HTML email using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python)

Comment: This is in fact something that happened to me so I think that the OP should maybe take a look at this

Comment: Same here, I added a `\n` in the middle of the line and the issue was resolved