# Python email using smtplib: 450, 'This mail is temporarily denied'

Tags: python, mime, smtplib

I made a small script to send an html email using smtplib based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python)

Basically what I want is to send an email to one of our subscribers automatically after certain conditions in our database are fulfilled
:

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

sender = "sender_email@domain.com"
receiver = "receiver_email@domain.com"

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "Test email"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Message body
text = "string message"
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>
       html message
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')


msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via external SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('mail.domain.com')

s.sendmail(sender, receiver, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

The issue is whenever I try to run the script to any email other than my own, i receive the following error:

```
      s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 742, in sendmail
    raise SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs)
smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused: {'other_email@domain.com': (450, 'This mail is temporarily denied')}
```

EDIT:

I checked my mail server configuration and tested for 3 different addresses, 2 of which I removed the spam filter and 1 for which I kept it and then ran the script.
The 2 emails with no spam filter received the email and the one with the filter did not, that is why I believe it is a spam issue, but it must be then how I am setting up the code that generates the email, or perhaps I'm missing a header?

Comment: This is almost certainly not an issue with your code. Email deliverability questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: which is the correct community then if it's not related to the p-language im using or the library smtplib?

Comment: Try this for a start: http://serverfault.com/questions/227242/prevent-mail-being-marked-as-spam

Comment: You are likely not providing the proper credentials to the server. What are the proper credentials? We have no idea; check with the service provider.

Comment: The belief "this is getting rejected as spam" is not supported by the evidence. The remote MTA is saying "go away" not "this is spam".

Comment: @msw you were right, I was missing the s.starttls() and s.login(me, pw) statements. Set your comment as an answer and I will mark it as such :) thx!

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the s.starttls() and s.login(me, pw) statements.
It works fine now.