# Send HTML Mail with Unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, unicode

I modified the example from the python docs, to test unicode in the email module.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, unicode_literals, print_function

import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# me == my email address
# you == recipient's email address
me = "my@email.com"
you = "your@email.com"

umlauts='German Umlauts: üöä ÜÖÄ ß'

# Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = umlauts
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
text = umlauts
html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       %s
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
""" % umlauts

# Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

# Attach parts into message container.
# According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
# the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

# Send the message via local SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
# sendmail function takes 3 arguments: sender's address, recipient's address
# and message to send - here it is sent as one string.
s.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#id4

I get this exception:

```
user@pc:~$ python src/sendhtmlmail.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/sendhtmlmail.py", line 37, in <module>
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/text.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.set_payload(_text, _charset)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 226, in set_payload
    self.set_charset(charset)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 262, in set_charset
    self._payload = self._payload.encode(charset.output_charset)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 16-18: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to handle unicode if you want to send a text+html mail?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly encode it to UTF-8.

```
part1 = MIMEText(text.encode('utf-8'), 'plain', 'utf-8')
part2 = MIMEText(html.encode('utf-8'), 'html', 'utf-8')
```

Or, avoid importing unicode_literals, and your strings will be bytes in the first place.

Comment: I use `unicode_literals` future import in all files, since the update to Python3 will happen sooner or later. And in the real code the characters are from db, not from the python source file :-)

Comment: Problem happens on Python 3 using Flask. Any advice?

Comment: This was the way to go before Python 3.6. The new `email` library API introduced in that version should be a lot more robust and easy to use. With `EmailMessage`, there is no need to separately encode things explicitly; just attach the parts you want to attach.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to send an email using ASCII, but instead you are passing Unicode characters to the email message.

**For specifics check:** 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html

In terms of a **coding example** I will blatantly link you to the following website.

http://www.askthepony.com/blog/2011/06/how-to-send-a-proper-unicode-encoded-email-using-python-2-7/

Comment: Last example link is 404. Sure it may have been available in the past but blatantly not anymore.