# Sending HTML email using Python with mHTML document

Tags: python, email

I have mHTML document created another programm and I want send it using Python.
But I can only send text from mHTML document without formatting.
Have any ideas how send text with formatting from mHTML?

Here’s my code:

```
import smtplib 
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.message import MIMEMessage 
import datetime 
import logging logger =logging.getLogger(__name__) 
sender = "###" 
smtpServerName = '###'

def sendEmail(subject, text, addressee):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = addressee
    text = MIMEText(text, 'html')
    msg.attach(text)
    smtpServer = smtplib.SMTP(smtpServerName)
    logger.info('Sending email to: ' + addressee + ' with subject: ' + subject)
    smtpServer.sendmail(sender, addressee.split(","), msg.as_string())
    smtpServer.quit()

text = open('mHTML_doc.mhtml') 
sendEmail('Hello!', text.read(), "###")
smtp_server =  "###" 
smtp_port = 25 
smtp_user = "###" 
smtp_pwd = "" smtp = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python.

Comment: No, this is another problem - I want to save the formatting of initional mHTML-document.