# Beautiful table alignment out when sending table with email

Tags: python, email, tabular, python-beautifultable

My table is printing fine in the console but when I email its alignment gets distorted a bit, any suggestion how to send it perfectly, as its printing in console?

```
from beautifultable import BeautifulTable
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import smtplib
table = BeautifulTable()
a= ["name", "age", "class"]
b=["Jacob", 1, "boy"]

table.column_headers =a
table.append_row(b)
print table

def mailfunction(table):


    fromaddr = "sender@gmail.com"
    toaddr = "receiver@gmail.com"
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    msg['From'] = fromaddr
    msg['To'] = toaddr

    msg['Subject'] = " TABLE PRINT"

    body = str(table)

    msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(fromaddr, "password")
    text = msg.as_string()
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
    server.quit()


mailfunction(table)
```

Console output:

```
+-------+-----+-------+
| name  | age | class |
+-------+-----+-------+
| Jacob |  1  |  boy  |
+-------+-----+-------+
```

Email output:

[image]

But when copy it from email to notepad alignments get back to normal

Comment: The email is simply not written into a monospaced font... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font

Comment: Consider either creating an html table with your data instead, or adding a monospaced font style definition in the html portion of the message. To send an html email with smtplib see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python