# Python3 How do I send Pandas Dataframe in an email

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
def call_panda():
    filename = 'C:\\file.csv'
    cols_to_use = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, nrows= 5,usecols=cols_to_use,index_col='col1')               
    # Send email
    me = 'me@email.com'
    you = 'you@email.com'
    textfile = df
    with open(textfile, 'rb') as fp:
        msg = MIMEText(fp.read())
        msg['Subject'] = 'Contents of file'
        msg['From'] = me
        msg['To'] = you
        s = smtplib.SMTP('mailhost.acme.net')
        s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
        s.quit()
```

Error Message is with open(textfile, 'rb') as fp:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame

Comment: Do you want to send it as text in the body of the message, or as an attachment (text, csv, etc.)?

Comment: I would like to embed it in the body of the email message.

Comment: You can convert a df to an HTML table - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html. I've never used this feature; I'm not sure if you have to export and attach an html file, or if you can embed it inline. (And, of course, your email has to support HTML.)

Answer (score 5):

Pandas has a `df.to_html` feature.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Copying Chris Albon: https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_join_merge_dataframe/

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {
        'subject_id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'first_name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', 'Ayoung'], 
        'last_name': ['Anderson', 'Ackerman', 'Ali', 'Aoni', 'Atiches']}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
df_a.to_html('df.html')
```

From here, check this thread for email tips: [Sending HTML email using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python)

It looks like you'll need to attach the HTML file; I'm not sure if it'll display online, and I don't have a mail server with which I can check.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, `df` defined as `textfile` is data that exists in current memory. Therefore, the `with open` command can not be executed. `with open` is a function that loads any file stored on the hard disk into memory.

Comment: Yes, that is the spirit of my question... is it possible to send a dataframe in an email or is my only option to send a .csv in html  or as an attachment?

Comment: The way to send a dataframe from what I know is to send it to csv. I do not know how to send it to html.

Comment: This should be commented and not posted as an answer!