# Linking local file while sending email using python

Tags: python, html, email

I am trying to attach a link to my local file while sending an email using python smtplib.

```
msg.attach(MIMEText(u'<a href="file:///C:\folder\file.txt">Link</a>', 'html'))
```

But it just comes as plain text in the email.

If I just use the link in a html page the link works.

```
<html>
<a href="file:///C:\folder\file.txt">Link</a>
</html>
```

How do I solve this?

Edit:

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

....
....
....
msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = self.username
msg['To'] = to
msg['Subject'] = subject

msg.attach(MIMEText(text))

mailServer = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.starttls()
mailServer.ehlo()
mailServer.login(self.username, self.password)
mailServer.sendmail(self.username, to, msg.as_string())
```

My code snippet of sending email is very similar to this

Comment: What are you using to send mail? Could you post a code snippet here?

Comment: I've edited the post

Comment: You don't give valid `HTML` to `MIMEText`. Add `<html>...</html>`.The parameter `MIMEText(..., 'html')` is only used in the header of `MIMEText`.

Comment: @stovfl I tried including it this way. It doesn't work.
`html_text += '<html>' + '\n'
html_text += '<a href = file:///C:\folder\file.txt">Link</a>' + '\n'
html_text += '</html>' + '\n'
msg.attach(MIMEText(html_text, 'html'))`

Comment: @ampat: Refer to [sending-html-email-using-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gmail does not support [local network URL](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/BoD_bRdPOC8/3qqq7EdnBAAJ) as of now. So that's why your link is not getting rendered in your mail.

You can use various alternative approaches, mentioned below in this link.

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/17269/put-a-link-to-a-network-share-in-a-gmail-message

Hope this answers your question!!!

Comment: How do you know that the OP is using Gmail?

Comment: I am using gmail