# Sending Outlook emails with win32 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook

I am relatively new to the coding world and trying to use the following python code to send automated email reports..
But i only get the dataframe in the automatic email and not the **"Hi this is a test email"** in the outlook email body.

Not really sure whats going wrong here.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'user@email.com'
mail.Subject = 'Insert Subject here'
mailerr1=df.to_html()
attachment  = 'shot.png'
mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)
mail.Body = "hi this is  a test email"
mail.HTMLBody = mailerr1

mail.Send()
```

Would really appreciate it if someone could give me a heads up on whats happening here..
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting your `Body` when you assign to `HTMLBody` your email client must be using the `HTMLBody` by default.

So you need to either combine the dataframe into the `Body` string, or add your `Body` as html to the other, here's an example:

```py
email.HTMLBody = '<p>hi this is a test email</p><br>' + mailerr1
```

You also need to format it into actual html though, see this question: [Sending HTML email using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python)

tl:dr

```py
email.HTMLBody = """
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>hi this is a test email</p><br>
""" + mailerr1 + """
  </body>
</html>
"""
```

Comment: It works.Thanks for the answer...
So Can I add multiple data frames, screenshots with different formatting for each of them into a single email body this way? 
That would be really helpful.

Comment: yes, just add more `+ my_dataframe_html` statements

Comment: If this satisfies your question, please remember to accept the answer

Comment: Just to follow up on this one, how do I consolidate my CSS code to the HTML here?

Comment: Here's a better in depth tutorial from Sprite Cloud that includes CSS support: https://www.spritecloud.com/creating-and-sending-html-e-mails-with-python/