# python/flask contact form not sending email to zoho account

Tags: python, flask, contact-form, zoho

I badly need your help, I have been trying to solve this problem for a week now, unsuccessfully.

this is my flask/python app[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@app.route('/home', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    return render_template("landing.html")

def contact():
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.form
        data = request.form
        send_email(data["name"], data["email"], data["subject"], data["message"])
        return render_template("landing.html", msg_sent=True)
    return render_template("landing.html", msg_sent=False)

def send_email(name, email, subject, message):
    email_message = f"Subject: {subject}\n\nName: {name}\nEmail: {email}\nMessage:{message}"
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.zoho.eu") as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(OWN_EMAIL, OWN_PASSWORD)
        connection.sendmail(OWN_EMAIL, OWN_EMAIL, email_message)
```

this is the landing.html part for the contact form:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
            <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" action="{{ url_for('home') }}" method="post" novalidate>
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                  <label>Email Address</label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                  <label>Subject</label>
                  <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter the subject.">
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                  <label>Message</label>
                  <textarea rows="5" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                  <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br>
              <div id="success"></div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessageButton">Send</button>
            </form>
```

I have 2 different errors depending if I am sending it from mobile or from Mac, the application logs shows status=200 if I am sending the from the mobile and status=404 if sent from Mac

```
2021-03-02T22:20:44.499516+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/home" host=www.redwhisker.com request_id=ff810eb4-138f-4c80-a605-785b130c1ddf fwd="86.141.236.165" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=10907 protocol=http
2021-03-02T22:22:08.721016+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/home" host=www.redwhisker.com request_id=cbe2cfc0-d197-4eef-9e97-7d021ac34b32 fwd="86.141.236.165" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=10907 protocol=http
2021-03-02T22:22:08.719985+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.8.36.208 - - [02/Mar/2021:22:22:08 +0000] "POST /home HTTP/1.1" 200 10744 "http://www.redwhisker.com/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; SM-G965F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.181 Mobile Safari/537.36"
2021-03-02T22:28:47.733308+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/home" host=www.redwhisker.com request_id=a2bead33-e8d5-4eed-879f-90ce41e52e7d fwd="86.141.236.165" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=10907 protocol=http
2021-03-02T22:28:47.730454+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.168.78 - - [02/Mar/2021:22:28:47 +0000] "POST /home HTTP/1.1" 200 10744 "http://www.redwhisker.com/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
2021-03-02T22:28:48.050319+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css.map" host=www.redwhisker.com request_id=8330d006-3ae4-46ed-a803-d2e93f6b92d6 fwd="86.141.236.165" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=http
2021-03-02T22:28:48.047736+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.168.78 - - [02/Mar/2021:22:28:48 +0000] "GET /static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css.map HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-02T22:28:48.235576+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.39.168.78 - - [02/Mar/2021:22:28:48 +0000] "GET /static/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"
2021-03-02T22:28:48.238169+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js.map" host=www.redwhisker.com request_id=6b290b88-8cbf-4b64-8185-24eae023afdb fwd="86.141.236.165" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=400 protocol=http
```

I am pretty new to flask/python and I am stuck on this can please someone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting email status codes, your flask code is fairly close to working.  The issue is probably just one or two configuration changes.

Here are some debugging suggestions:

1. If there is a debug option in Flask/Python's email code, turn that on and see if you get better detail about the failure.
2. Search Stackoverflow for `[zoho][smtp]` and read through the issues. This is a common problem. The issues will be in different coding languages but they are mostly all sending email via Zoho's smtp server.
3. Try sending an email via python without flask in the middle just to reduce the complexity and see if you can work out the issues from there.  This Stackoverflow  link discusses some of the python mailing options: [Sending HTML email using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python?rq=1)