# Flask send rendered html template on email

Tags: python, html, flask, pyscript

I'm using Flask to generate API and passing the data using rendered template to create charts on html page using py-script.

Please let me know how can I send the rendered html page with all charts over email?

At least if I get an idea to store the rendered html page will also work.

```
def test():
    try:
        df = {'C': 20, 'C++': -15, 'Java': 30,
                'Python': 35}

        cars = ['AUDI', 'BMW', 'FORD', 'TESLA', 'JAGUAR', 'MERCEDES']
        point = [23, 17, 35, 29, 12, 41]

        #df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(cars, point)), columns=['cars', 'point'])
        # showing the prediction results in a UI

        return render_template('test.html',data=df,ct=cars,pt=point)



    except Exception as e:
        print('The Exception message is: ',e)
        logging.debug(e)
        return 'something is wrong'
```

Test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
      <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>

      <py-env>
        - pandas
        - numpy
        - matplotlib
      </py-env>
  </head>
  <body>

<py-script>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = list({{data}}.keys())
x = list({{data}}.values())

plt.barh(y, x, color=['red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan'])

# setting label of y-axis
plt.ylabel("pen sold")

# setting label of x-axis
plt.xlabel("price")
plt.title("Horizontal bar graph")
plt

</py-script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Regards,
Rohan

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/#flask.render_template): `flask.render_template(template_name_or_list, **context)`

> Renders a template from the template folder with the given context.

This means that through the `render_template` function you are able to generate a string starting from a file (the template) and any parameters passed to the template.

Instead of returning the result of the `render_template`, save it in a variable and then send the content via email.

```
def test():
    try:
        df = {'C': 20, 'C++': -15, 'Java': 30,
                'Python': 35}

        cars = ['AUDI', 'BMW', 'FORD', 'TESLA', 'JAGUAR', 'MERCEDES']
        point = [23, 17, 35, 29, 12, 41]

        #df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(cars, point)), columns=['cars', 'point'])
        # showing the prediction results in a UI

        my_html = render_template('test.html',data=df,ct=cars,pt=point)
        send_mail("test@test.com", "subject", my_html)


    except Exception as e:
        print('The Exception message is: ',e)
        logging.debug(e)
        raise e
```

Note that if the template contains css files served by your own application, for example:
`<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{{url_for ('static', filename = 'style.css')}}">`, the email will be displayed correctly only if your application It is running. Otherwise embed the css directly into the template, which I recommend if your purpose is to generate an email.

Comment: I did try with your suggestions but unable to achieve the end result as getting error. It would be great help if you can provide code for send_mail() function. Please find error: * Debug mode: on, The Exception message is:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n  <head>\n      <link rel="stylesheet"...all html code

Comment: [take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/send-html-emails-with-python). The error you posted in the comment refers to a method that takes the path of a file as a parameter, but you are passing it a string containing some html.

Comment: I tried to send my_html variable via email it is getting sent but body is containing the html code stored in my_html. If I save that email body manually to .html file I am getting desired output.