# How to send newsletter from my pc?

Tags: python, smtp

Is there a way to send newsletter from my pc ( ubuntu 10.04 ) and python ?

maybe with a smtp library ?

Comment: Maybe... What have you tried? What has not worked? What has?

Comment: Why don't you use a mail client? (Thunderbird, Evolution, Outlook, …)

Comment: If you can use PHP then PHPmailer maybe a good  option.

Comment: You'll also need an SMTP *server* to talk to...

Comment: This belongs on superuser.com

Comment: It could be a legitimate programming question, it's rather broad and ambiguous at the moment though.

Comment: @awoodland - Disagree. Any actual question buried in there is a system admin or poweruser question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is going to be a regular task, install [Mailman](http://www.gnu.org/software/mailman/index.html) (if you don't already have it) and learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [script](http://kutuma.blogspot.com/2007/08/sending-emails-via-gmail-with-python.html) that can be used to send an email using a gmail or Google domain apps email account.  It uses Google's SMTP server, so you don't need to configure one locally.

Using its 'mail' function, it's easy to send a message.  For example:

```
# function signature: def mail(to, subject, text, attach)
mail("some.person@some.address.com",
   "Hello from python!",
   "This is a email sent with python",
   "my_picture.jpg")
```

You could easily modify the 'mail' function to remove 'attach' if you don't want an attachment, or make it an optional keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to pipe the output of your python program to the mail command on an appropriately configured system:

```
python my.py | mail -s "test mail sending" "your@email.com"
```

(For Ubuntu on your PC that probably means using the SMTP servers from your ISP as a smarthost for exim or another MTA)

If that doesn't cut it you're going to want to make your python script talk to some mailserver(s), usually using SMTP. There's a python [library](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) for this, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505/sending-mail-from-python-using-smtp) for an example generating MIME and probably others too.