# Encoding mail subject (SMTP) in Python with non-ASCII characters

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, smtp, cjk

I am using Python module `MimeWriter` to construct a message and smtplib to send a mail constructed message is:

```
file msg.txt:
-----------------------
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
from: me<me@abc.com>
to: me@abc.com
subject: 主題

Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8

主題
```

I use the code below to send a mail:

```
import smtplib
s=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.abc.com')
toList = ['me@abc.com']
f=open('msg.txt') #above msg in msg.txt file
msg=f.read()
f.close()
s.sendmail('me@abc.com',toList,msg)
```

I get mail body correctly but subject is not proper,

```
subject: some junk characters

主題           <- body is correct.
```

Please suggest? Is there any way to specify the decoding to be used for the subject also,
as being specified for the body. How can I get the subject decoded correctly?

Comment: oh chinese charaters are garbled here after posting the question

Comment: related: [How can I send email using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9272257/4279)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From http://docs.python.org/library/email.header.html

```
from email.message import Message
from email.header import Header
msg = Message()
msg['Subject'] = Header('主題', 'utf-8')
print msg.as_string()
```

> Subject: =?utf-8?b?5Li76aGM?=

more simple:

```
from email.header import Header
print Header('主題', 'utf-8').encode()
```

> =?utf-8?b?5Li76aGM?=

as complement decode may made with:

```
from email.header import decode_header
a = decode_header("""=?utf-8?b?5Li76aGM?=""")[0]
print(a[0].decode(a[1]))
```

Reference:
[Python - email header decoding UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331351/python-email-header-decoding-utf-8)

Comment: Note that this uses the [`email.message.Message`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.compat32-message.html#compat32-message) API, which was superseded by `email.message.EmailMessage` in Python 3.6. With the new API you must assign a string: `msg['Subject'] = 'unicode string'`, as [assigning Header objects is not supported](https://bugs.python.org/issue21095). In my experience as of 3.7.3 the "legacy" API works better - some encoding bugs are fixed in 3.8

Comment: Thanks for head up

Answer (score 8):

The subject is transmitted as an SMTP header, and they are required to be [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)-only. To support encodings in the subject you need to prefix the subject with whatever encoding you want to use. In your case, I would suggest prefix the subject with ?UTF-8?B? which means [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded.

In other words, I believe your subject header should more or less look like this:

```
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?JiMyMDAyNzsmIzM4OTg4Ow=?=
```

In PHP you could go about it like this:

```php
// Convert subject to base64
$subject_base64 = base64_encode($subject);
fwrite($smtp, "Subject: =?UTF-8?B?{$subject_base64}?=\r\n");
```

In Python:

```
import base64
subject_base64 = base64.encodestring(subject).strip()
subject_line = "Subject: =?UTF-8?B?%s?=" % subject_base64
```

Comment: i'll try this, meantime is there any python api to convert to above format. i.e. automatically append the characters based on required encoding

Comment: I'm not sure - I just remembered that part from when I was messing around with this issue a while ago. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910104/python-how-to-send-utf-8-e-mail#answer-5910530) seems to suggest that it is done right if you use the MIMEMultipart class instead of MimeWriter.

Comment: you should look up here [how to generate internationalized headers](http://docs.python.org/library/email.header.html)

Answer (score 1):

In short, if you use the `EmailMessage` API, you should code like this:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.header import Header
msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = Header('主題', 'utf-8').encode()
```

Answer from @Sérgio cannot be used in the `EmailMessage` API, cause **only string object** can be assigned to `EmailMessage()["Subject"]`, but not an `email.header.Header` object.