# How can I send email using Python?

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I am writing a program that sends  an email using Python. What I have learned from various forums is the following piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import smtplib
sender = "sachinites@gmail.com"
receivers = ["abhisheks@cse.iitb.ac.in"]
yourname = "Abhishek Sagar"
recvname = "receptionist"
sub = "Testing email"
body = "who cares"
message = "From: " + yourname + "\n" 
message = message + "To: " + recvname + "\n"
message = message + "Subject: " + sub + "\n" 
message = message + body
try:
    print "Sending email to " + recvname + "...",
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    username = 'XYZ@gmail.com'  
    password = '*****'  
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()  
    server.login(username,password)  
    server.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
    server.quit()
    print "successfully sent!"
except  Exception:
    print "Error: unable to send email"
```

But it is simply printing ""Error: unable to send email" and exits out on the terminal. How might I resolve this?

I modified the last two lines to

```
except Exception, error:
    print "Unable to send e-mail: '%s'." % str(error)
```

I get the following error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./2.py", line 45, in <module>
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 239, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 295, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/smtplib.py", line 273, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((port, host), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 514, in create_connection
    raise error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: I see you're new to stackoverflow, welcome!  Make sure you use the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to properly format your posts.  This helps us read your question more easily and increases your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending mail from Python using SMTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505/sending-mail-from-python-using-smtp)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If message headers, payload contain non-ascii characters then they should be encoded:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from email.header    import Header
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from getpass         import getpass
from smtplib         import SMTP_SSL


login, password = 'user@gmail.com', getpass('Gmail password:')
recipients = [login]

# create message
msg = MIMEText('message body…', 'plain', 'utf-8')
msg['Subject'] = Header('subject…', 'utf-8')
msg['From'] = login
msg['To'] = ", ".join(recipients)

# send it via gmail
s = SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465, timeout=10)
s.set_debuglevel(1)
try:
    s.login(login, password)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], recipients, msg.as_string())
finally:
    s.quit()
```

Comment: Gmail is now pretty tight with what devices can sign in to the account. If, like me, you have issues using code like this on a remote machine you can try logging into gmail account and checking the "Allow less secure apps" option. There are also tools to authorize specific apps

Comment: @jprockbelly: don't compromise security. It works even on the account with 2-step verification. Just generate an app password for your script.

Answer (score 6):

If you print the error message, you will likely get a comprehensive description of *what* error occurred.  Try (no pun intended) this:

```
try:
    # ...
except Exception, error:
    print "Unable to send e-mail: '%s'." % str(error)
```

If, after reading the error message, you still do not understand your error, please update your question with the error message and we can help you some more.

---

**Update after additional information**:

the error message

> socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

means the remote end (e.g. the GMail SMTP server) is refusing the network connection.  If you take a look at the [smtplib.SMTP constructor](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP), it seems you should change

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
```

to the following.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
```

Comment: after doing what you said , i get the following error :

Sending email to receptionist... Unable to send e-mail: '[Errno 110] Connection timed out' . i am behind the proxy , so do i need to add something extra to the code.

Comment: @AbhishekSagar: SMTP configuration is a complex topic.  Perhaps you can try one of the alternate ports?  See [configuring other email clients](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287) in the GMail frequently asked questions.

Comment: yes, i install postfix , and gave up the idea when i searched Configuring the SMTP ! its really complex.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you use the localhost as the SMTP server, then the connection was refused. Your localhost didn't have an SMTP sever running I guess, you need to make sure the SMTP server you connect is valid.