# Why Gmail doesn't display my RFC 2047-encoded From header?

Tags: python, email, encoding, gmail, rfc

My Python application uses email.header.Header (http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html ) to encode all headers of outgoing email (including From header), just like indicated here: [Encoding mail subject (SMTP) in Python with non-ASCII characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913170/encoding-mail-subject-smtp-in-python-with-non-ascii-characters)

It works perfectly for ASCII sender names, but for senders like

> Adrian Płonka <pokemon@myservice.com>

it produces

> From: =?utf-8?q?Adrian_P=C5=82onka_=3Cpokemon=40myservice=2Ecom=3E?=

Unfortunately, Gmail apparently doesn't like this way of encoding as it displays the sender as (unknown) and marks the whole message as Spam.

How do I properly encode non-ASCII senders?

Comment: Show the call that you use to do the encoding, please.

Comment: I'm using `message['From'] = email.header.Header(email.utils.formataddr((u'Adrian Płonka', u'pokemon@myservice.com'), charset))`.Anyway, the result (as I can see it both in the log and in Gmail's "show original message") is: `=?utf-8?q?Adrian_P=C5=82onka_=3Cpokemon=40myservice=2Ecom=3E?=`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper way to encode that is

```
From: =?utf-8?q?Adrian_P=C5=82onka?= <pokemon@myservice.com>
```

That is, only the name part, not the actual email terminus, may be RFC2047-encoded.

Comment: What if the email address has international characters, e.g. 施設@blah.jp

Comment: UTF-8 is supported in addresses with the [internationalization extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Internationalization) and an address in this format would be embedded without encoding it; but this facility has only existed for a limited time, so it's unlikely to work very well in many clients just yet. But on systems which support this, you can use bare UTF-8 throughout the headers.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_email

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant way I can think of in order to achieve the outcome from @tripleee's answer would be:

```
message['From'] = formataddr((charset.header_encode('Adrian Płonka'), 'pokemon@myservice.com'))
```

where `charset` is an `email.charset.Charset` object, I created with:

```
charset = email.charset.Charset()
charset.body_encoding = email.charset.QP
charset.header_encoding = email.charset.QP
charset.input_charset = 'utf-8'
charset.output_charset = 'utf-8'
charset.input_codec = 'utf-8'
charset.output_codec = 'utf-8'
```

It displays correctly with Gmail as well as with other providers.

This was non-trivial for me to find, hope it helps...

Comment: Has this changed with the `email` library overhaul introduced in Python 3.5, and made the default implementation in 3.6?

Comment: To belatedly answer my own question, looks like the OP's original code `str(Header(formataddr((u'Adrian Płonka', u'pokemon@myservice.com'), 'utf-8')))` would now return the correct value 
`'=?utf-8?q?Adrian_P=C5=82onka?= <pokemon@myservice.com>'` as of Python 3.5.1.  The new "proper" way to do it is probably a lot simpler still.