# How to send an email with Python?

Tags: python, email, function, smtplib

This code works and sends me an email just fine:

```
import smtplib
#SERVER = "localhost"

FROM = 'monty@python.com'

TO = ["jon@mycompany.com"] # must be a list

SUBJECT = "Hello!"

TEXT = "This message was sent with Python's smtplib."

# Prepare actual message

message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

# Send the mail

server = smtplib.SMTP('myserver')
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

However if I try to wrap it in a function like this:

```
def sendMail(FROM,TO,SUBJECT,TEXT,SERVER):
    import smtplib
    """this is some test documentation in the function"""
    message = """\
        From: %s
        To: %s
        Subject: %s
        %s
        """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    # Send the mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()
```

and call it I get the following errors:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python31/mailtest1.py", line 8, in <module>
    sendmail.sendMail(sender,recipients,subject,body,server)
  File "C:/Python31\sendmail.py", line 13, in sendMail
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\smtplib.py", line 720, in sendmail
    self.rset()
  File "C:\Python31\lib\smtplib.py", line 444, in rset
    return self.docmd("rset")
  File "C:\Python31\lib\smtplib.py", line 368, in docmd
    return self.getreply()
  File "C:\Python31\lib\smtplib.py", line 345, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Can anyone help me understand why?

Comment: I call the function by importing it into my main module and passing the parameters which I have defined into it.

Comment: Although @Arrieta's suggestion to use the email package is the best way to solve this, your approach can work.  The differences between your two versions are in the string: (1) as @NickODell points out, you have leading whitespace in the function version.  Headers should have no leading space (unless they are wrapped).  (2) unless TEXT includes a leading blank line, you've lost the separator between headers and body.

Comment: gmail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python

Answer (score 266, accepted):

I recommend that you use the standard packages [`email`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html) and [`smtplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) together to send email. Please look at the following example (reproduced from the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)). Notice that if you follow this approach, the "simple" task is indeed simple, and the more complex tasks (like attaching binary objects or sending plain/HTML multipart messages) are accomplished very rapidly.

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Import the email modules we'll need
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Open a plain text file for reading.  For this example, assume that
# the text file contains only ASCII characters.
with open(textfile, 'rb') as fp:
    # Create a text/plain message
    msg = MIMEText(fp.read())

# me == the sender's email address
# you == the recipient's email address
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of %s' % textfile
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you

# Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
# envelope header.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

For sending email to multiple destinations, you can also follow the example in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html):

```
# Import smtplib for the actual sending function
import smtplib

# Here are the email package modules we'll need
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

# Create the container (outer) email message.
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Our family reunion'
# me == the sender's email address
# family = the list of all recipients' email addresses
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = ', '.join(family)
msg.preamble = 'Our family reunion'

# Assume we know that the image files are all in PNG format
for file in pngfiles:
    # Open the files in binary mode.  Let the MIMEImage class automatically
    # guess the specific image type.
    with open(file, 'rb') as fp:
        img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    msg.attach(img)

# Send the email via our own SMTP server.
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(me, family, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

As you can see, the header `To` in the `MIMEText` object must be a string consisting of email addresses separated by commas. On the other hand, the second argument to the `sendmail` function must be a list of strings (each string is an email address).

So, if you have three email addresses: `person1@example.com`, `person2@example.com`, and `person3@example.com`, you can do as follows (obvious sections omitted):

```
to = ["person1@example.com", "person2@example.com", "person3@example.com"]
msg['To'] = ",".join(to)
s.sendmail(me, to, msg.as_string())
```

the `",".join(to)` part makes a single string out of the list, separated by commas.

From your questions I gather that you have not gone through [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) - it is a MUST if you want to get anywhere in Python - the documentation is mostly excellent for the standard library.

Comment: Thank you this works very nicely from within a function, however how can I send to multiple recipients? Since msg[to] looks like it's a dictionary key, I tried seperating the msg[to] with a semicolon but that does not seem to work.

Comment: @cloud311 exactly as you have it in your code. It wants a string delimited with commas:  `", ".join(["a@example.com", "b@example.net"])`

Comment: Note also that the To: header has different semantics than the envelope recipient.  For example, you can use '"Tony Meyer" <tony.meyer@gmail.com>' as an address in the To: header, but the envelope recipient must be only "tony.meyer@gmail.com".  To build a 'nice' To: address, use email.utils.formataddr, like email.utils.formataddr("Tony Meyer", "tony.meyer@gmail.com").

Comment: Small improvement: the file should be opened using `with`: `with open(textfile, 'rb') as fp:`. The explicit close can be dropped, as the `with` block will close the file even if an error occurs inside it.

Comment: @cloud311 I don't know how helpful this is, but I saw in a similar question where OP had `recipient` as a parameter for his function, and the variable it corresponded to looked like this: `TO = recipient if type(recipient) is list else [recipient]`... this way it would sent a list of recipients to the server as the recipient, if you choose to put a list of recipients into the argument.

Comment: @Escualo can you share the link of the python tutorial you are referring to?

Comment: Not specific to this answer, but when connecting to any SMTP server that you don't control, you should consider the possibility that it is unreachable, slow, rejecting connections or whatever else. Code-wise you'll get an exception, but you then need to find a way to re-try the sending a bit later on. If you talk to your own sendmail/postfix, then it'll take care of that re-sending for you.

Comment: @escualo If you're sending this to localhost (in the first example), how can you see the output?

Comment: The Python documentation weirdly shows how to muck with the MIME preamble but you really should just pretend that it doesn't exist. There should be very few situations where your recipients can see the preamble, and fewer still where replacing the standard preamble is a good idea.

Answer (score 110):

When I need to mail in Python, I use the [mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com) API which gets a lot of the headaches with sending mails sorted out. They have a wonderful app/api that allows you to send 5,000 free emails per month.

Sending an email would be like this:

```
def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages",
        auth=("api", "YOUR_API_KEY"),
        data={"from": "Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>",
              "to": ["bar@example.com", "YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME"],
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})
```

You can also track events and lots more, see [the quickstart guide](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart.html).

Comment: @PascalvKooten Absolutely amusing to follow your constant advertising for yagmail (yes, Sir, I will consider it next time, Sir ;). But I find it very confusing that almost no one seems to care for OPs issue, but rather suggests much different solutions. It's as if I am asking how to change bulbs in my 2009 smart and the answer is: Buy a real Mercedes...

Comment: @flaschbier The reason no one cares about the OPs issue is because the title is wrong. "How to send an email with Python?" is the actual reason people come to look when they click that question, and they'd expect an answer that [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) can provide: nice and short. There you go. More yagmail advertisement.

Comment: @PascalvKooten No offence. I was assuming your mission is to provide better email support in Python and I love that. Had I found yagmail last time I had to implement mail notifications, I absolutely would have considered it (the MIT license and installing 3rd party software would have been possible in that environment). Regarding the title of the question, I think you are absolutely right. Why not suggest an edit?

Comment: Ah I see, no edit can be suggested because the question is being rejected as "too much code" now :( Pity that.

Comment: Just to say that for Mailgun customers, sending mail by webservices is considerably more bandwidth-friendly than via SMTP (especially if using any attachments).

Comment: When I use their sandbox, the mails all go to my spam folder, and the sender is marked not authentic by Gmail. Any advice?

Answer (score 61):

I'd like to help you with sending emails by advising the yagmail package (I'm the maintainer, sorry for the advertising, but I feel it can really help!).

The whole code for you would be:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP(FROM, 'pass')
yag.send(TO, SUBJECT, TEXT)
```

Note that I provide defaults for all arguments, for example if you want to send to yourself, you can omit `TO`, if you don't want a subject, you can omit it also.

Furthermore, the goal is also to make it really easy to attach html code or images (and other files).

Where you put contents you can do something like:

```
contents = ['Body text, and here is an embedded image:', 'http://somedomain/image.png',
            'You can also find an audio file attached.', '/local/path/song.mp3']
```

Wow, how easy it is to send attachments! This would take like 20 lines without yagmail ;)

Also, if you set it up once, you'll never have to enter the password again (and have it safely stored). In your case you can do something like:

```
import yagmail
yagmail.SMTP().send(contents = contents)
```

which is much more concise!

I'd invite you to have a look at the [github](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail) or install it directly with `pip install yagmail`.

Comment: Can I use `yagmail` other than gmail? I am trying to use for my own SMTP server.

Comment: @dtgq Thanks for your concern. Personally, I don't see the attack vector. If someone is going to change the file under the path you want to send, then it doesn't matter if you have an `Attachment` class; it's still the same thing. If they can change your code, then they can do anything they want anyway (with/without root, that's the same w.r.t. email sending). This seems to me like the typical "it is convenient/magical so it must be less secure". I'm curious what real threat you see?

Comment: This only works for gmail users aka this is utterly useless for pretty much any professional use.

Answer (score 21):

Here is an example on Python `3.x`, much simpler than `2.x`:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
def send_mail(to_email, subject, message, server='smtp.example.cn',
              from_email='xx@example.com'):
    # import smtplib
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = from_email
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(to_email)
    msg.set_content(message)
    print(msg)
    server = smtplib.SMTP(server)
    server.set_debuglevel(1)
    server.login(from_email, 'password')  # user & password
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
    print('successfully sent the mail.')
```

call this function:

```
send_mail(to_email=['12345@qq.com', '12345@126.com'],
          subject='hello', message='Your analysis has done!')
```

#### below may only for Chinese user:

If you use 126/163, 网易邮箱, you need to set"客户端授权密码", like below:

[image]

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41470149/2803344
https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html#email-examples

Comment: Note to future readers:  There's also an `SMTP_SSL` class and there is a `port` keyword argument that might need to be set.  The unencrypted version just hangs if the server requires SSL.

Comment: I like this version. I built my example based on this.

Answer (score 18):

There is indentation problem. The code below will work:

```
import textwrap

def sendMail(FROM,TO,SUBJECT,TEXT,SERVER):
    import smtplib
    """this is some test documentation in the function"""
    message = textwrap.dedent("""\
        From: %s
        To: %s
        Subject: %s
        %s
        """ % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT))
    # Send the mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()
```

---

Comment: @geotheory the `SERVER` variable that is passed into the function is the user credentials.

Comment: Manually piecing together a valid SMTP message with simple string interpolation is not recommended, and your answer has a bug which illustrates this perfectly. (The body needs to start with an empty line for this to be a valid message.) For anything involving character sets other than plain text in 1980s 7-bit English-only US-ASCII (attachments, internationalization, and other MIME support) you **really** want to use a library which handles this stuff. The Python `email` library does this reasonably well (particularly since 3.6) though it still requires some understanding of what you're doing.

Answer (score 8):

While indenting your code in the function (which is ok), you did also indent the lines of the raw message string. But leading white space implies folding (concatenation) of the header lines, as described in sections 2.2.3 and 3.2.3 of [RFC 2822 - Internet Message Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822):

> Each header field is logically a single line of characters comprising
> the field name, the colon, and the field body.  For convenience
> however, and to deal with the 998/78 character limitations per line,
> the field body portion of a header field can be split into a multiple
> line representation; this is called "folding".

In the function form of your `sendmail` call, all lines are starting with white space and so are "unfolded" (concatenated) and you are trying to send

```
From: monty@python.com    To: jon@mycompany.com    Subject: Hello!    This message was sent with Python's smtplib.
```

Other than our mind suggests, `smtplib` will not understand the `To:` and `Subject:` headers any longer, because these names are only recognized at the beginning of a line. Instead `smtplib` will assume a very long sender email address:

```
monty@python.com    To: jon@mycompany.com    Subject: Hello!    This message was sent with Python's smtplib.
```

This won't work and so comes your Exception.

The solution is simple: Just preserve the `message` string as it was before.  This can be done by a function (as Zeeshan suggested) or right away in the source code:

```
import smtplib

def sendMail(FROM,TO,SUBJECT,TEXT,SERVER):
    """this is some test documentation in the function"""
    message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
    # Send the mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
    server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
    server.quit()
```

Now the unfolding does not occur and you send

```
From: monty@python.com
To: jon@mycompany.com
Subject: Hello!

This message was sent with Python's smtplib.
```

which is what works and what was done by your old code.

Note that I was also preserving the empty line between headers and body to accommodate section 3.5 of [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) (which is required) and put the include outside the function according to the Python style guide [PEP-0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) (which is optional).

Comment: NOTE: One of the values of this post is the nuanced explanation of how the SMTP protocol works.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have granted permission for both Sender and Receiver to send emails and receive them from Unknown sources(External Sources) in the Email Account.

```
import smtplib

#Ports 465 and 587 are intended for email client to email server communication - sending email
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

#starttls() is a way to take an existing insecure connection and upgrade it to a secure connection using SSL/TLS.
server.starttls()

#Next, log in to the server
server.login("#email", "#password")

msg = "Hello! This Message was sent by the help of Python"

#Send the mail
server.sendmail("#Sender", "#Reciever", msg)
```

Comment: `msg` is not a valid SMTP message, and will simply appear to disappear into the ether if your mail server accepts it.

Comment: Basically see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077603/getting-a-blank-email/55078455#55078455

Answer (score 3):

It's probably putting tabs into your message. Print out message before you pass it to sendMail.

Answer (score 3):

It's worth noting that the SMTP module supports the context manager so there is no need to manually call quit(), this will guarantee it is always called even if there is an exception.

```
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as server:
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(user, password)
        server.sendmail(from, to, body)
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been satisfied with the package options for sending emails and I decided to make and open source my own email sender. It is easy to use and capable of advanced use cases.

To install:

```
pip install redmail
```

Usage:

```
from redmail import EmailSender
email = EmailSender(
    host="<SMTP HOST ADDRESS>",
    port=<PORT NUMBER>,
)

email.send(
    sender="me@example.com",
    receivers=["you@example.com"],
    subject="An example email",
    text="Hi, this is text body.",
    html="<h1>Hi,</h1><p>this is HTML body</p>"
)
```

If your server requires a user and a password, just pass `user_name` and `password` to the `EmailSender`.

I have included a lot of features wrapped in the `send` method:

- Include attachments
- Include images directly to the HTML body
- Jinja templating
- Prettier HTML tables out of the box

Documentation:
https://red-mail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Source code: https://github.com/Miksus/red-mail

Comment: The ultimate winner.  HOT!!

Comment: TLS supported ?

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd put in my two bits here since I have just figured out how this works.

It appears that you don't have the port specified on your SERVER connection settings, this effected me a little bit when I was trying to connect to my SMTP server that isn't using the default port: 25.

According to the smtplib.SMTP docs, your ehlo or helo request/response should automatically be taken care of, so you shouldn't have to worry about this (but might be something to confirm if all else fails).

Another thing to ask yourself is have you allowed SMTP connections on your SMTP server itself? For some sites like GMAIL and ZOHO you have to actually go in and activate the IMAP connections within the email account. Your mail server might not allow SMTP connections that don't come from 'localhost' perhaps? Something to look into.

The final thing is you might want to try and initiate the connection on TLS. Most servers now require this type of authentication.

You'll see I've jammed two TO fields into my email. The msg['TO'] and msg['FROM'] msg dictionary items allows the correct information to show up in the headers of the email itself, which one sees on the receiving end of the email in the To/From fields (you might even be able to add a Reply To field in here. The TO and FROM fields themselves are what the server requires. I know I've heard of some email servers rejecting emails if they don't have the proper email headers in place.

This is the code I've used, in a function, that works for me to email the content of a *.txt file using my local computer and a remote SMTP server (ZOHO as shown):

```
def emailResults(folder, filename):

    # body of the message
    doc = folder + filename + '.txt'
    with open(doc, 'r') as readText:
        msg = MIMEText(readText.read())

    # headers
    TO = 'to_user@domain.com'
    msg['To'] = TO
    FROM = 'from_user@domain.com'
    msg['From'] = FROM
    msg['Subject'] = 'email subject |' + filename

    # SMTP
    send = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.zoho.com', 587)
    send.starttls()
    send.login('from_user@domain.com', 'password')
    send.sendmail(FROM, TO, msg.as_string())
    send.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation using gmail let's say:

```
import smtplib

def send_email(email_address: str, subject: str, body: str):
"""
send_email sends an email to the email address specified in the
argument.

Parameters
----------
email_address: email address of the recipient
subject: subject of the email
body: body of the email
"""

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("email_address", "password")
server.sendmail("email_address", email_address,
                "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject, body))
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import smtplib

s = smtplib.SMTP(your smtp server, smtp port) #SMTP session

message = "Hii!!!"

s.sendmail("sender", "Receiver", message) # sending the mail

s.quit() # terminating the session
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple function `send_email()` for email sending with `smtplib` and `email` packages (link to my [article](https://mljar.com/blog/python-send-email/)). It additionally uses `dotenv` package to loads the sender email and password (please don't keep secrets in the code!). I was using Gmail for email service. The password was the `App Password` (here is [Google docs](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) on how to generate `App Password`).

```py
import os
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from dotenv import load_dotenv
_ = load_dotenv()


def send_email(to, subject, message):
    try:
        email_address = os.environ.get("EMAIL_ADDRESS")
        email_password = os.environ.get("EMAIL_PASSWORD")

        if email_address is None or email_password is None:
            # no email address or password
            # something is not configured properly
            print("Did you set email address and password correctly?")
            return False

        # create email
        msg = EmailMessage()
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = email_address
        msg['To'] = to
        msg.set_content(message)

        # send email
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465) as smtp:
            smtp.login(email_address, email_password)
            smtp.send_message(msg)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print("Problem during send email")
        print(str(e))
    return False
```

The above approach is OK for simple email sending. If you are looking for more advanced features, such as HTML content or attachments - it, of course, can be hand-coded, but I would recommend using existing packages, for example [`yagmail`](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail).

Gmail has a limit of 500 emails per day. For sending many emails per day please consider transactional email service providers, like Amazon SES, MailGun, MailJet, or SendGrid.

Answer (score 1):

just to complement the answer and so that your mail delivery system can be scalable.

I recommend having a configuration file (it can be .json, .yml, .ini, etc) with the sender's email configuration , password and recipients.

This way you can create different customizable items according to your needs.

Below is a small example with 3 files, config, functions and main. Text-only mailing.

**`config_email.ini`**

```
[email_1]
sender = test@test.com
password = XXXXXXXXXXX
recipients= ["email_2@test.com", "email_2@test.com"]

[email_2]
sender = test_2@test.com
password = XXXXXXXXXXX
recipients= ["email_2@test.com", "email_2@test.com", "email_3@test.com"]
```

These items will be called from **`main.py`**, which will return their respective values.

File with functions **`functions_email.py`**:

```
import smtplib,configparser,json
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def get_credentials(item):
    parse = configparser.ConfigParser()
    parse.read('config_email.ini')
    sender = parse[item]['sender ']
    password = parse[item]['password']
    recipients= json.loads(parse[item]['recipients'])
    return sender,password,recipients

def get_msg(sender,recipients,subject,mail_body):
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = sender 
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)       
    text = """\
    """+mail_body+""" """
    part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
    msg.attach(part1)
    return msg

def send_email(msg,sender,password,recipients):
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.test.com')
    s.login(sender,password)
    s.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
```

File **`main.py`**:

```
from functions_email import *

sender,password,recipients = get_credenciales('email_2')
subject= 'text to subject'
mail_body = 'body....................'
msg = get_msg(sender,recipients ,subject,mail_body)    
send_email(msg,sender,password,recipients)
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

@belter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47571812/19716381) looks simple and usable, but doesn't work on most modern servers as most of them use `ssl`. The following solution is a slight modification and it works.

```
import smtplib, ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage

PORT = 465
SERVER = "smtp.example.com"
CONTEXT = ssl.create_default_context()
USERNAME = "abc"
PASSWORD = "123"

def send_email(to_email, subject, message, from_email="abc@example.com"):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg["Subject"] = subject
    msg["From"] = from_email
    msg["To"] = to_email
    msg.set_content(message)
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(SERVER, PORT, context=CONTEXT)
    server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()

send_email(to_email=["def@gmail.com", "hij@gmail.com"], subject="Test mail", message="Testing email")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 587  # For starttls
smtp_server = "smtp.office365.com"
sender_email = "170111018@student.mit.edu.tr"
receiver_email = "professordave@hotmail.com"
password = "12345678"
message = """\
Subject: Final exam

Teacher when is the final exam?"""

def SendMailf():
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
        server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
        server.starttls(context=context)
        server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
        print("mail send")
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of fiddling with the examples e.g [here](https://coderzcolumn.com/tutorials/python/smtplib-simple-guide-to-sending-mails-using-python)
this now works for me:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# SMTP sendmail server mail relay
host = 'mail.server.com'
port = 587 # starttls not SSL 465 e.g gmail, port 25 blocked by most ISPs & AWS
sender_email = 'name@server.com'
recipient_email = 'name@domain.com'
password = 'YourSMTPServerAuthenticationPass'
subject = "Server - "
body = "Message from server"

def sendemail(host, port, sender_email, recipient_email, password, subject, body):
    try:
        p1 = f'<p><HR><BR>{recipient_email}<BR>'
        p2 = f'<h2><font color="green">{subject}</font></h2>'
        p3 = f'<p>{body}'
        p4 = f'<p>Kind Regards,<BR><BR>{sender_email}<BR><HR>'
        
        message = MIMEText((p1+p2+p3+p4), 'html')  
        # servers may not accept non RFC 5321 / RFC 5322 / compliant TXT & HTML typos

        message['From'] = f'Sender Name <{sender_email}>'
        message['To'] = f'Receiver Name <{recipient_email}>'
        message['Cc'] = f'Receiver2 Name <>'
        message['Subject'] = f'{subject}'
        msg = message.as_string()

        server = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
        print("Connection Status: Connected")
        server.set_debuglevel(1)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(sender_email, password)
        print("Connection Status: Logged in")
        server.sendmail(sender_email, recipient_email, msg)
        print("Status: Email as HTML successfully sent")

    except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print("Error: unable to send email")

# Run
sendemail(host, port, sender_email, recipient_email, password, subject, body)
print("Status: Exit")
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing new here compared to the other answers, except that it joins all of the following:

- use TLS (STARTTLS in the example below)

  - use `ssl.create_default_context()` to validate server certificate(!)
- do not use low level smtplib methods

  - no `ehlo()`, no `quit()`
  - use `with` statement to replace some of those
- leverage `EmailMessage` class to simplify message creation and sending even further
- use `inspect.cleandoc()` only to allow for reasonable multi-line string literals

Example:

```
import inspect
import smtplib
import ssl

from email.message import EmailMessage

# a reasonably secure client context way better than None
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()

def mail(message):
    with smtplib.SMTP('mail.example.com', port=587) as c:
        c.starttls(context=ssl_context)
        c.login(username, password)
        c.send_message(message)

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['From'] = 'from@example.com'
msg['To'] = 'to@example.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'hello mail'
msg.set_content(inspect.cleandoc('''
    Dear receiver,

    This is some mail...

    Regards,
    me
    '''))

mail(msg)
```

Answer (score -2):

As far your code is concerned, there doesn't seem to be anything fundamentally wrong with it except that, it is unclear how you're actually calling that function. All I can think of is that when your server is not responding then you will get this SMTPServerDisconnected error. If you lookup the getreply() function in smtplib (excerpt below), you will get an idea.

```
def getreply(self):
    """Get a reply from the server.

    Returns a tuple consisting of:

      - server response code (e.g. '250', or such, if all goes well)
        Note: returns -1 if it can't read response code.

      - server response string corresponding to response code (multiline
        responses are converted to a single, multiline string).

    Raises SMTPServerDisconnected if end-of-file is reached.
    """
```

check an example at https://github.com/rreddy80/sendEmails/blob/master/sendEmailAttachments.py that also uses a function call to send an email, if that's what you're trying to do (DRY approach).