# Trying to send a mail from Outlook 2007 using Python (win32com.client)

Tags: python, automation, outlook

I'm attempting to start some Outlook 2007 automation with Python. I got this great script (below) from Steve Townsend on this thread: [Send Outlook Email Via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332577/send-outlook-email-via-python)

but I'm having trouble getting started with this.

```
import win32com.client

def send_mail_via_com(text, subject, recipient, profilename="Outlook2007"):
    s = win32com.client.Dispatch("Mapi.Session")
    o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    s.Logon(profilename)

    Msg = o.CreateItem(0)
    Msg.To = recipient

    Msg.CC = "moreaddresses here"
    Msg.BCC = "address"

    Msg.Subject = subject
    Msg.Body = text

    #attachment1 = "Path to attachment no. 1"
    #attachment2 = "Path to attachment no. 2"
    #Msg.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
    #Msg.Attachments.Add(attachment2)

    Msg.Send()


send_mail_via_com("test text","test subject", "removed@security.obv","Outlook2007")
```

But I get the following Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 83, in _
GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROJECTS\Python\send_mail_test.py", line 25, in <module>
    send_mail_via_com("test text","test subject", "removed@security.obv","Outloo
k2007")
  File "C:\PROJECTS\Python\send_mail_test.py", line 4, in send_mail_via_com
    s = win32com.client.Dispatch("Mapi.Session")
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 95, in
Dispatch
    dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,c
lsctx)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 108, in
_GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
    return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 85, in _
GetGoodDispatch
    IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.II
D_IDispatch)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221005, 'Invalid class string', None, None)
```

It's probably something silly that I've missed.

It's Python 3.2 and PyWin32 has been installed

Many Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

never mind...

```
import win32com.client
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "I AM SUBJECT!!"
newMail.Body = "I AM IN THE BODY\nSO AM I!!!"
newMail.To = "who_to_send_to@example.com"
#newMail.CC = "moreaddresses here"
#newMail.BCC = "address"
#attachment1 = "Path to attachment no. 1"
#attachment2 = "Path to attachment no. 2"
#newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
#newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment2)
#newMail.display()
newMail.Send()
```

This works on Python 3.2.3 with PyWin32 installed. I have commented out some lines for if you want to play with this.

[2017 EDIT] - adding HTML email support (in case it's handy for anyone)

```
import win32com.client

#some constants (from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa219371%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
olFormatHTML = 2
olFormatPlain = 1
olFormatRichText = 3
olFormatUnspecified = 0
olMailItem = 0x0


obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "I AM SUBJECT!!"
newMail.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML    #or olFormatRichText or olFormatPlain
newMail.HTMLBody = "<h1>I am a title</h1><p>I am a paragraph</p>"
newMail.To = "who_to_send_to@example.com; anotherrecipient@email.fake"

# carbon copies and attachments (optional)

#newMail.CC = "moreaddresses here"
#newMail.BCC = "address"
#attachment1 = "Path to attachment no. 1"
#attachment2 = "Path to attachment no. 2"
#newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
#newMail.Attachments.Add(attachment2)

# open up in a new window and allow review before send
newMail.display()

# or just use this instead of .display() if you want to send immediately
#newMail.Send()
```

Answer (score 1):

the code above works on Python 2.7 as well. 
the error in the original post is caused by:

> > > s = win32com.client.Dispatch("Mapi.Session")
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client__init__.py", line 95, in Dispatch
> > >           dispatch, userName = dynamic._GetGoodDispatchAndUserName(dispatch,userName,clsctx)
> > >         File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 108, in _GetGoodDispatchAndUserName
> > >           return (_GetGoodDispatch(IDispatch, clsctx), userName)
> > >         File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 85, in _GetGoodDispatch
> > >           IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)

it used to work in Outlook 2003. I suppose 2007 simply does not need the MAPI and logon.