# Change "from" field option in outlook using python via win32com

Tags: python, outlook, win32com

In addition to this thread [send outlook mail via win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12704508/trying-to-send-a-mail-from-outlook-2007-using-python-win32com-client), i'd like to know if there is a possibility to use `mail.From` alike method. When you create an email, you can choose from what email you'd like to send it. 
And for the future, where could i get this information from? I mean do those commands work with COM object of outlook application?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible with win32com but this can be done using smtplib.

Comment: @VIKASH JAISWAL, can you provide possible solution or lead to an idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code which I have been using for long time and hopefully will work for you as well,

```
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import Encoders

def sendMail(to, subject, text):
    assert type(to)==list

    fro = "abc@xyz.com" # use your from email here
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = fro
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html'))
    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('mailhost.abcd.co.in') #use your mailhost here, it's dummy.
    smtp.sendmail("", to, msg.as_string() )
    smtp.close()

TOADDR   = ['abc@xyz.com'] # list of emails address to be sent to

html = """\
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>Hi!<br>
       How are you?<br>
       Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
"""

sendMail( TOADDR, "hello",html)
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Are there any preferences for IMAP/POP servers?

Comment: Since I have never used something like that so don't know about it but I see there are other libraries that have. For instance look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156485/receve-replys-from-gmail-with-smtplib-python