# Using Python to scrape emails for text, log the text in an Excel file, and write a new email containing the text

Tags: python, excel, outlook

At my job, I receive email news updates each day that I have to (a) log in an Excel file and (b) reformat in a new email sent out to a distribution list.

The task is manual and takes up to 30 minutes a day. I've done as much as I can on my end with using keyboard shortcuts to minimize the time in Outlook and Excel and wondered if I could use Python to do some or all of the task for me.

The key steps, as mentioned, are (a) going into the specific folder, copying the emails' text, and pasting in Excel and (b) placing that text in a new email with formatting. I wish I could just forward the emails to the distribution list, but I was told I can't do this. Also I don't know that Python can apply formatting that's in Outlook, but I figure I can get help writing some VBA code to apply the template format.

Any guidance on what I can and can't do is greatly appreciated. I'm new to using Python at work but am excited about the challenge of removing manual tasks and freeing up time to do more exciting projects!

Comment: Hi there! If you are new to python, I recommend that you watch a beginners course on YouTube to understand the concepts of python. If you want to create an excel file with python, you should look into some modules such as xlwt, XlsXcessive, and openpyxl.

Comment: @Frederik.L that is irrelevant to the question that was asked.

Comment: I think this answer can help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/17887528/6487316.