# no bool object but traceback says: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, outlook, jira-rest-api

is this problem because of line: *mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)*? 
i want to send n e-mails in for loop in python.

```
for aaa in jira.search_issues(JQL,startAt=0, maxResults=50):
    print(aaa)
    try:
        tworca = (jira.issue(aaa).fields.creator.name)
        przypisany =(jira.issue(aaa).fields.assignee.name)
        import win32com.client as win32
        outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.To = tworca + ';' + przypisany
        mail.Subject = 'blablabla'
        mail.Body = 'Message body'
        mail.send()
        print ("OK!")
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR: " + str(e))

print ("done!")
```

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx.py", line 12, in <module>
    mail.send()
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Comment: The easiest explanation is `mail.send` is actually a `bool` object.  Have you checked its `type()`?

Comment: it appears that `outlook.CreateItem` returns a bool

Comment: No, `mail.send` is the bool.

Comment: mail.send is boll. Do you know how to corect my script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `mail.Send()`.  `mail.send` is a `bool` object.

Remember Python is case sensitive.

See relevant: [Send Outlook Email Via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332577/send-outlook-email-via-python#17887528)

Another tip: don't assume how your code work like "there's no `bool` object".  The traceback is never wrong and is the best starting point to tell you where you should begin your investigation.  It can be a typo or simple misuse of attribute. 
 In this case, clearly the interpreter is telling you `mail.send` is not what you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error as you:

> mail.send() TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable".

I  changed the code from `mail.send()` to `mail.send`, and the problem was solved.

Comment: Welcome aboard. Keep in mind that proper capitalisation, grammar, spelling, et al, is important. You can read more details about SO guidelines for posts in the help section from a link on the nav bar.  Also please use markdown (or the editing menu) to format code & error messages as such. Looking forward to seeing more of your contributions.