# Python code which implements voting button option for an outlook mail

Tags: python, automation, outlook, scripting

I am working on an automation script which should take certain email-ids from an excel/csv sheet and send a mail to these email-ids which should have a voting option. I came across a package pyoutlook but I doubt if i can do any such task.

If not python, i can automate in any other programming language as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can automate Outlook from Python:

```
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'To address'
mail.Subject = 'Message subject'
mail.Body = 'Message body'
mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>HTML Message body</h2>' #this field is optional

mail.VotingOptions = "Yes;No"

mail.Send()
```

The [MailItem.VotingOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.votingoptions) property sets a string specifying a delimited string containing the voting options for the mail message. This property uses the character specified in the value name, `sList`, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` in the Windows registry, as the delimiter for multiple voting options.

You may find the [Send Outlook Email Via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332577/send-outlook-email-via-python) page helpful.