# Sending mail using python in linux machine

Tags: python, email

am receiving mail when I run the code in jupyter, but i tried in my Linux box via python am not receiving any mail.

Here is the below code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import smtplib
import ssl

port = 587
smtp_server = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"
sender = "example@outlook.com"
recipient = "example@outlook.com"
sender_password = "Password"

message = """
Subject: This is a test message
Sent using Python."""

SSL_context = ssl.create_default_context()

with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.starttls(context=SSL_context)
    server.login(sender, sender_password)
    server.sendmail(sender, recipient, message)
```

Comment: In your `with smtplib` try to enable debug and see what the messages are: `server.set_debuglevel(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to connect Outlook with SMTP. You should require your email account allows smtp, which is not necessarily enabled by default.

Also, you can try other solutions based on libraries;

```py
from O365 import Message

html_template =     """ 
            <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                    {}
            </body>
            </html>
        """

final_html_data = html_template.format(df.to_html(index=False))

o365_auth = ('sender_username@company_email.com','Password')
m = Message(auth=o365_auth)
m.setRecipients('receiver_username@company_email.com')
m.setSubject('Weekly report')
m.setBodyHTML(final)
m.sendMessage()
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52534847/5942941

or
install redmail:

```bash
pip install redmail
```

and try to be use this sample;

```py
from redmail import outlook

outlook.user_name = "example@hotmail.com"
outlook.password = "<MY PASSWORD>"

outlook.send(
    receivers=["you@example.com"],
    subject="An example",
    text="Hi, this is an example."
)
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71056577/5942941

Comment: in my box, pip is showing an error what might be the case?

Comment: When I try to install on my pc, I can install succesfully. Please would you share your python version? pip version? your Computer OS?