# modifying the excel files using pandas in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, libraries, pyautogui

I am trying to modify an existing Excel file using the pandas library in Python.

i used the file contents for my automated email triggering the email to the customer

once the mail sent i just want to update the status of the customer in the excel file

is there a way to do this using pandas library in python?

```
subprocess.Popen('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\OUTLOOK')
    time.sleep(10)
    for i in range(0, len(DAYS_COUNT)):
        if df['Acceptance status'][i] in NO_FOLLOWUP:
            pass
        if df['Days \ncount'][i] >= 7 and df['Platform'][i] == "Email":
            time.sleep(3)
            print(df['Company Name/ \nEmail Address'][i])
            send_to = df['Company Name/ \nEmail Address'][i]
            pyautogui.click(x=25, y=244)  # sent_click
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.click(x=118, y=158)  # search_sent_click
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.click(x=286, y=74)  # search_by_to_click
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.write(df['Company Name/ \nEmail Address'][i])
            time.sleep(2)
            # pyautogui.click(x=207, y=254)  # first_item_click
            pyautogui.click(x=186, y=276)  # first_item_click
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.click(x=639, y=162)  # forward_click
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.write(f"{send_to};")  # to_address
            time.sleep(5)
            pyautogui.press("tab")
            pyautogui.write(f"{CC};")  # cc_address
            time.sleep(5)
            pyautogui.press("tab")
            pyautogui.tripleClick(x=607, y=252)  # subject_line_remove_existing
            subject_status = df['Acceptance status'][i].lower()
            pyautogui.write(MAIL_SUBJECT[subject_status])  # subject
            time.sleep(5)
            pyautogui.press("tab")
            pyautogui.press("tab")
            mail_body_status = df['Acceptance status'][i].lower()
            if df['Remarks'][i] == "economic times":
                pyautogui.write(BD_FRESH_MAIL['economic_mail_body'])
            else:
                pyautogui.write(MAIL_BODY[mail_body_status])  # mail_body
            time.sleep(5)
            # pyautogui.press("delete")
            # pyautogui.press("delete")
            pyautogui.click(x=489, y=205)  # send_click
            time.sleep(1)
```

once the mail sent i just want to update the status of the customer in the excel file

and save it without losing the data in the excel file

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the pandas `DataFrame` data structure. You can read the excel file using `read_csv` function and after that use `DataFrame.at` function to set a new value.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("PATH TO EXCEL FILE")
row_index = 5 # ROW THAT NEEDS TO BE UPDATES
col_name = "STATUS"
data.at[row_index, col_name] = True # SET THE NEW VALUE
data.to_csv("PATH TO A NEW EXCEL FILE")
```

After update, you can save the data frame using `to_csv` function passing a new file path or use the same path to overwrite the older excel file.

Pandas doc about `.at` function: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html

Answer (score 0):

Of course! Pandas is using openpyxl to complete some of the excel-specific actions, though, so you may be able to simply use that library instead.

You should be able to insert your excel-manipulation code after your desired trigger action.

Example of reading an excel sheet into memory with both pandas and openpyxl. Let us know what else you'd like to do!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xlsx')

from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'empty_book.xlsx')
```

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html

P.s. You might be able to simplify (and error-proof) your pyautogui actions with the  win32com library using outlook programmatically, instead of using the GUI.

[Send Outlook Email Via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332577/send-outlook-email-via-python/17887528#17887528)

Answer (score 0):

I use `openpyxl` to write excel files if I need more control.
Otherwise just pd.to_excel().
This is just a general idea:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter("path_to_file.xlsx", 
  mode="a", engine="openpyxl") as writer:
     
  data_frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Customers")
```

or

```
df.to_excel("name.xlsx")
```

If you are at a stage where you need to update df first (just an example):

```
# Your source of emailed customers
# this is just a demo
listOfReceivers = [nam1, name2, name3]

def checkName(customer):
   # may want to strip() and lower() all names
   if customer in listOfReceivers:
      return True
   else:
     return False


# Change columns to match yours
df['Emailed'] = df['Customers'].apply(checkName)
df.to_excel("name.xlsx")
```