# Collect Python output till current execution and assign it to variable for sending email

Tags: python, mime-types, smtplib, text-processing

I am doing text processing using Python in which I am looking for a specific text in a console log and printing every matched line. This is accomplished by a function called:

`get_matched_log_lines(url, search_pattern, print_pattern)` where `url` = from which I get my log, `search_pattern` = my target search pattern, `print_pattern` = the way I want to print my output(its, `%s.%s`)

How do I send this entire output of function `get_matched_log_lines()` via email? Emailing function code is already written by me in Python.

Here is what I think/attempted so far:

```
email_content = get_matched_log_lines(url, search_pattern, print_pattern)
TO = 'recipient email address'
FROM ='sender email address'

#emailing function - py_mail
py_mail("Test email subject", email_content, TO, FROM)
```

This provides me an empty email.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I just edited my question asking... How do I send this entire output of function get_matched_log_lines() via email? I hope thats clearer now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email with Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270782/how-to-send-an-email-with-python)

Comment: I think it was not exactly the duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270782/how-to-send-an-email-with-python but it definitely help me getting my answer. I collected all the steps and posting my answer below. Thanks PyNEwbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer based on the suggestions by PyNEwbie:

```
   def get_matched_log_lines(url, search_pattern, print_pattern):
        out = open("output_file.txt", "w")
        for something in somthings:
              test = print_pattern % matched_line
              print >>out, test
            out.close()
```

^^ just a general example (syntax maybe incorrect). The idea is to open the `file in write mode` and then dumping the output in it.

```
fp = open("output_file.txt", 'r')
    # Create a text/plain message
    msg = fp.read()
    fp.close()
    email_content = msg
```

Then open the same `file in read mode` and store its output to some var (in my case `email_content`)

Finally send an email with that `email_content`,

```
 email_content = get_matched_log_lines(url, search_pattern, print_pattern)
    TO = 'recipient email address'
    FROM ='sender email address'

#emailing function - py_mail
py_mail("Test email subject", email_content, TO, FROM)
```