# Advanced mailto use in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to send an email with custom recipient, subject and body in Python.
This means I don't want to use [Python's smtp packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270782/how-to-send-an-email-with-python), but something like [webbrowser](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/webbrowser.html?highlight=webbrowser#module-webbrowser) because I need this to open the default email client (Thunderbird in my case) with said arguments.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("mailto:?to=aaa@email.com&subject=mysubject", new=1)
```

works but I need it to get the recipient from a string I previously found and body from a text file I previously created.

Is there any "simple" way to do it that I cannot find?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use string concatenation to create the argument to `webbrowser.open()`. What's the problem?

Comment: Why does customizing the recipient, subject,and browser mean you have to do it in the web browser? The smtp package can fill those fields in.

Comment: I didn't phrase it well, editing the post now.

Comment: OK, so what's the problem? Don't you know how to concatenate strings in Python using the `+` operator?

Comment: Do you need also a function for getting the recipient from somewhere and save it to a string or you have no problem for that and you only need a way to get the body from a text file? If you need help also for the recipient, provide more information.

Comment: No I don't know how to concatenate strings in this case. I never coded before in my life, just trying to learn by doing, most the time I can, this time I can't.


I got the string that contains the recipient email and the text file for the body. What I need is how to tell Python "Open Thunderbird, use X as recipient, Y as subject and Z.txt as body".

Comment: Do you have only 1 recipient or more than 1? If more than 1, do you have a fixed list that never changes? Where do you get the recipients? Do you need to get them programmatically from somewhere or you can simply write a list that you will use for composing the email? If you provide clear info I can give you a complete solution.

Comment: ok so if you just use a variable for the recipient and the subject, I'll code the rest of the program for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use the variables **recipient** and **subject** to store the relative values. Simply replace the example text between single quotes with your real value.

```
recipient = 'emailaddress'
subject = 'mysubject'
```

The subject field can't contain white spaces, so they have to be url encoded using %20 ASCII code

```
subject = subject.replace(' ', '%20')
```

the function above replaces the white space with "%20" and assigns the modified subject to the same variable since you can reuse it, you really don't need another one in this case.

It's possible to use also the **urllib** module for url encoding (see **urllib.urlencode()** method), but it can be done simply using the **replace()** method so you can avoid importing another module just for that.

Now you need to load the text from a text file and store it in a variable.
Imagine you have a text file called **body.txt**:

```
with open('body.txt', 'r') as b:
    body = b.read()
```

Note that I assumed **body.txt** is in the same directory of your Python script, otherwise in the filename parameter you have to include the full absolute or relative path to the file, followed by the file name.

I used the **open()** function and I provide 2 parameters: the first one is the **filename**, the second one is the **mode** you want to open the file with. You want to read the file so you have to open it in **read mode** (**'r'**). Once you open the file you need to be able to identify the file with a variable in order to perform some operations on it. This kind of variable is technically called **handle**, in this case I called it **b**.

Now for reading ALL the text you can use **b.read()** and then you can assign it to the variable **body**. (If you wanted to read it line by line, you would have done: **b.readline()** but you don't want this in this case.)

Note that I used the **with** statement, this is the preferred way for opening and working with files, because it will automatically close the file at the end, else you would have to do it manually. Before **with** was available you would have to do something like this:

```
b = open('body.txt', 'r'):
body = b.read()
b.close()
```

Now it's better to url encode also the string contained in the variable **body**, so we do the same thing we did for the **subject**:

```
body = body.replace(' ', '%20')
```

Now it's time to use the **webbrowser** module and provide the data you got so far as parameter, concatenating the strings.

```
webbrowser.open('mailto:?to=' + recipient + '&subject=' + subject + '&body=' + body, new=1)
```

Obviously you also need to import the **webbrowser** module before using it.
I'll rewrite the whole program without comments for clarity:

```
import webbrowser

recipient = 'emailaddress'
subject = 'mysubject'

with open('body.txt', 'r') as b:
    body = b.read()

body = body.replace(' ', '%20')

webbrowser.open('mailto:?to=' + recipient + '&subject=' + subject + '&body=' + body, new=1)
```

Comment: Great answer with excellent explanations, thank you very much for taking the time to write this down for me!

Comment: prego @FabioMancin :)

Comment: any ideas on how to insert a .jpg either as an attachment or embedded in the body text?

Comment: @Fabio any ideas on how to insert attachments?

Comment: I’d strongly suggest to use the mentioned [urllib.parse.urlencode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode). If, e.g., the body contains ampersands, the suggested string replacement is not enough.
I would even go so far and suggest to not implement your own encoding/decoding/quoting/unquoting in general if there is a good library available. It is too easy to overlook some edge case. Since it is part of the standard python library in this case, I would not hesitate to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation.

```
recipient = 'aaa@email.com'
subject = 'mysubject'
body = 'This is a message'
webbrowser.open("mailto:?to='+ recipient + '&subject=' + subject + "&body=" + body, new=1)
```