# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object for a code which is supposed to send an email

Tags: python, string, email, byte, typeerror

Hi I was writing this code but when I run it it gives me the error saying:'TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object' Can you guys please tell me what I did wrong and what I should do to avoid from getting this error?
SCRIPT:

```
import smtplib
marks=input('Marks:')
email_send=input('Which Email should this message be sent to?')
marks_mess='Marks:',marks
email_user= 'my email'
server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_user,'my password')
server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,marks_mess)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending an email via the Python email library throws error "expected string or bytes-like object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469952/sending-an-email-via-the-python-email-library-throws-error-expected-string-or-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
marks_mess='Marks:',marks
```

assigns a tuple containing the two strings to `marks_mess`; it's equivalent to:

```
marks_mess = ('Marks:', marks)
```

If you want to concatenate them into a single string, you have to use `+`, not `,`.

```
marks_mess = 'Marks:' + marks
```

Comment: Thank you very much!