# Send email using python

Tags: python

I want to send emails from my Gmail account using python. I followed steps given in this stackoverflow post: [How to send an email with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270782/how-to-send-an-email-with-python)

But, my the mails that I sent do not reach the addresses.

This is the error that I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "something.py", line 24, in <module>
    server = smtplib.SMTP('myserver')
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 317, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 292, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

What should I be doing here?

Comment: What is the error? Please be more specific

Comment: Maybe destination has a spam protection.

Comment: Check if you can send an email from the command line.  Google quit accepting smtp messages from users without a recognized domain.  I had to use my msn account to do this.

Comment: enamoria, BladeMight, bivouac0: I have updated the post with the error that I am getting. Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: You're not meant to copy `server = smtplib.SMTP('myserver')` exactly, replace `'myserver'` with your email provider's SMTP server. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html for more on how to use smtplib.

Answer (score 3):

What you've get is a DNS query error indicating that domain `myserver` does not exist.

You have to replace the argument `myserver` in `server = smtplib.SMTP('myserver')` with the actual address of SMTP server, such as `smtp.mail.yahoo.com`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
import smtplib
server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login('your_email@gmail.com','your_password')
server.sendmail('your_email@gmail.com','your_email@gmail.com','test email')
```