# Function send a mail Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, email, dictionary

Let me explain my problem I am looking to make a program that compares user absences in 2 different tools. The result of their absence is returned in 2 Excel file or in which I make a sum of each absence for each user thanks to a dictionary in python then I compare the 2 dictionary in order to find an error and suddenly the program returns the name of the user for whom the number of absences is not equal. And so I would like to know how to make my program send an email to the user concerned.

Sum of absences :

```
 for row in range(1,253):
                  id2.append(feuille_2.cell_value(row, 2))
                  absence2.append(float(feuille_2.cell_value(row, 9)))

                result = {}
                for name in set(id2):
                    result[name] = 0


                for i in range(len(id2)):
                   hours = float(absence2[i])
                   name = id2[i]
                   result[name] += hours

                for name, hours in result.items():
                   print(name + ":\t" + str(hours))   



                id4 = [id1]          
                absence = []





                for row in range(1,361):
                    absence.append(feuille_1.cell_value(row, 10))

                    id4.append(id1)

                    print(absence)


                result2 = {}
                for name2 in set(id4):
                    result2[name2] = 0


                for i in range(len(id4)):
                   hours2 = absence[i]
                   name2 = id4[i]
                   result2[name2] += hours2

                   print(result2)
```

Comparaison of two dictionaries :

```
print("Seulement sur Sugar:", ", ".join(set(result).difference(result2)))
                print("Seulement sur Chrnos:", ", ".join(set(result2).difference(result)))

                for key in set(result).intersection(result2):
                    if result[key]!=result2[key]:
                        print("%s n'a pas declarer ses congée"% (key))
```

And I want help i want a function who send an email to each user concerned. After the comparaison

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send an email with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270782/how-to-send-an-email-with-python)

Comment: Not really i want help for in my case with my programm

Comment: You said, "I would like to know how to make my program send an email to the user concerned." Then you said in your comment, "I want help for in my case with my program.", which I cannot understand what you are asking. You need to try to explain better what it is you are looking for help with. Is it "Who has not declared their absences?"