# How to send email with python

Tags: python, email

```
import smtplib, ssl

port = 587  # For starttls
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
sender_email = "jppythons@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "jppythons@gmail.com"
password = input("pass")
message = """\
Subject: Email Test1

First eamil ever using Python."""

context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

The only thing it returns when I run my code is my password... nothing else happens, no errors, and no email

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send an email with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270782/how-to-send-an-email-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

i would use try except so you can see if there are any errors.  for example,

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

```
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
except Exception as e:
    # Print any error messages to stdout
    print(e)
finally:
    server.quit()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Python Testes/Emails.py", line 21
    except Exception as e:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: can you please share your updated code - or a few lines around line 21?

Comment: context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server:
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()  # Can be omitted
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    server.quit()

Comment: i don't see "try" in your code.  it needs to be formatted like above.  in short, replace with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, port) as server with the above try: server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)

Comment: context = ssl.create_default_context()
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls(context=context)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
except Exception as e:
    # Print any error messages to stdout
    print(e)
finally:
    server.quit()

It returns:
my password again, nothing else

Comment: what version of python are you using?  i just tested with python 3.8.x and received email

Comment: I´m running Thonny in a raspberry 2 with Python 3.7.3

Comment: Already using python 3.8 :), never less the code runs with no errors but noting happens ;(