# How to send individualized emails to each person in a list

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out how to send an email to each individual, where each email is different. I would have all of the content set up just to input in the email, but I am just unsure on how or if I can do so.

have put together a code to send emails to multiple recipients. However each recipient receives all mails instead of his own.

Example Dataframe:

```
email                  content
 mark@gmail.com         Hi Mark, bla bla
 eve@gmail.com          Hi Eve, bla bla
 john@gmail.com         Hi, John bla bla
```

is it possible to to send an email to each person, with the individual content? I obviously also have to mention that this list will most likely be growing to a couple thousand people. Would this be too much for a simple PC to handle?

Thanks!

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270782/how-to-send-an-email-with-python

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

def func(email,msg):

```
    return 'hello '+email.split('@')[0] +', '+ msg

print(
    func('mark@gmail.com','bla bla bla ')
    )
```