# How to start TLS on an active connection in python?

Tags: python, sockets, smtp, ssl

The following is my current code for connecting to gmail's smtp server on port 587. After issuing the STARTTLS command how would I finish negotiating the TLS session and begin issuing commands such as AUTH LOGIN and MAIL FROM? I have ommitted my Base64 encoded gmail username and replaced it with xxxxxxxx near the bottom of my code.

My output from this program as it is, is:

> 220 mx.google.com ESMTP y10sm3296641yhd.6
>
> 250-mx.google.com at your service, [75.66.47.144]
>
> 250-SIZE 35882577
>
> 250-8BITMIME
>
> 250-STARTTLS
>
> 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>
> 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS

```
from socket import *
import ssl
msg = "\r\n smtp.."
endmsg = "\r\n.\r\n"

# Mailserver hostname and port to be used.
mailserver = ("smtp.gmail.com", 587)


# Create a socket and create an active TCP connection with the mailserver
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM);
clientSocket.connect(mailserver)

# Read server response
recv = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv
if recv[:3] != '220':
    print '220 reply not received from server.'

# Send EHLO command and print server response.
ehloCommand = 'EHLO smtp.google.com\r\n'
clientSocket.send(ehloCommand)

recv1 = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv1
if recv1[:3] != '250':
    print '250 reply not received from server.'

# Send STARTTLS command to server and print server response
command = "STARTTLS\r\n"
clientSocket.send(command)

recv1 = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv1
if recv[:3] != '220':
    print '220 reply not received from server.'

# SEND AUTH LOGIN command and Base64 encoded username
command = "AUTH LOGIN xxxxxxxxxxxxx\r\n"
clientSocket.send(command)

recv1 = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv1
```

Comment: why not just use http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html ?

Comment: @MK. I want to do this manually as an exercise.

Comment: I figured so. If not using ssl module written in C, there is a pure python ssl module somewhere. maybe start from ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, keyfile, certfile)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can ssl wrap a connected socket.  This will give you the idea:

```
import ssl
import base64
from socket import *


cc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
cc.connect(("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
# cc.read(..)

cc.send('helo tester.com\r\n')
cc.send('starttls\r\n')
# cc.read(..) If the server responds ok to starttls
#             tls negotiation needs to happen and all
#             communication is then over the SSL socket 

scc = ssl.wrap_socket(cc, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
scc.send('auth login\r\n')
# scc.read(..)

scc.send(base64.b64encode('username')+'\r\n')
scc.send(base64.b64encode('password')+'\r\n')

# css.send(
#  mail from:
#  rcpt to:
#  data
#  etc
```

look at the AUTH LOGIN section of this page for info about the username/password encoding: http://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference-auth.htm

> After that the AUTH LOGIN command has been sent to the server, the
>   server asks for username and password by sending BASE64 encoded text
>   (questions) to the client. “VXNlcm5hbWU6” is the BASE64 encoded text
>   for the word "Username" and “UGFzc3dvcmQ6” is the BASE64 encoded text
>   for the word "Password" in the example above. The client sends
>   username and password also using BASE64 encoding. "adlxdkej", in the
>   example above, is a BASE64 encoded username and "lkujsefxlj" is a
>   BASE64 encoded password.

Comment: I want to add that if you don't do `cc.read(...)` after `cc.send('starttls\r\n')`, then the SSL wrapper will get confused by the server's "ready to start TLS" message and give an "unknown protocol" error.