# Not able to send email - Django

Tags: django, django-email

My `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend' 
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True 
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com' 
EMAIL_PORT = 587 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'rakil@gmail.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*******' 
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'testing@testing.com
```

But a mail is not sent to the address, in the console the `print.html` is printing when I click on `send_email`, but it's not sending any email.

I am using Django 1.3.7 and Python 2.6.

I don't know the problem is with the version or some logic problem.

Comment: Have you turned on debugging? `DEBUG = True` in settings.py? Then, can u for example send email using your other local mail clients? Are you certain about your local smtp settings being fine? Are there any errors in the system mail or http logs?

Comment: what's your email config in `settings.py`?

Comment: @nemesisfixx DEBUG = TRUE in settings.py,how to check the latter one

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo settings.py updated

Comment: @user2086641 on which OS are u testing this? If it's a *nix box, try testing that u can actually send email using the `mail` command for example. Otherwise, another thing to check is to see whether the ajax request even hits the server... ;-/

Comment: @nemesisfixx using fedora 14(Linux)

Comment: All,in console i am getting the template,on send_mail

Comment: @nemesisfixx Ajax is returning the success message,but mail not send

Comment: Fire up a manage.py shell and try to send mail from there.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In `settings.py`

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

`console.EmailBackend` will print the mail in the console. So using

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

solved my problem. It is already documented here: [Django docs: Email](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/email/)

Comment: This little change makes every natural way to proceed the good way to proceed. With everything right in except of this line, it worked always without error but the email wasn't sent. Now there are no errors and the email is sent (: .

Comment: Thank you. #Added this to exceed the min. number of words for comment

Answer (score 1):

I personally just switched to my production server when this happened.  Because this is a new IP location, Google attempted to protect my account by blocking the sign-in.

To fix this, I followed the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27515833/13042142):

First, **enable** access to less secure apps in your Google account here: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

Since I had already done this, and my problem was now because of a new IP address, I had to manually confirm the next sign-in attempt using this link: https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

See the linked answer for more information.