# Sending Email direct from EXE

Tags: email

I have a windows application that has been developed and it sends an email when a certain parameter is true.

I used LAVABIT to send the email direct but now this has closed so I am looking for another email service to use. Any suggestions? Gmail, Ymail etc don't seem to allow me to send from a program.

Comment: [You can send using gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/trying-to-send-email-gmail-as-mail-provider-using-python), you just have to authenticate it first...

Comment: I will try, when you say authenticate it first, how do you mean, are there steps?

Comment: Yes, they're the standard ones for connecting to any SMTP. What they are specifically will depend on what programming language and SMTP library you';re using. If you have a problem connecting maybe it would be better to post your code and update your question with some information?