# Cant send email via python using gmail - smtplib.SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server

Tags: python, email, python-2.7, smtp, smtplib

I just want to send an email in python with an attachment

```
import smtplib, os
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import Encoders

def send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=[], server="localhost"):
    assert type(send_to)==list
    assert type(files)==list

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = send_from
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )

    for f in files:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload( open(f,"rb").read() )
        Encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(f))
        msg.attach(part)

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    smtp.login('fu@gmail.com','fu')
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
    smtp.close()

ATTACHMENTS = ['/tmp/2013-11-04-test.csv']
send_from=['fu@gmail.com']
send_to=['fu@gmail.com']
subject='adfadfadf'
text = 'adfadfadf'
send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=ATTACHMENTS)
```

How do I auth? I have to provide a username and password.  How?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/miliza-devops/classes/utilities.py", line 133, in <module>
    send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=ATTACHMENTS)
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/miliza-devops/classes/utilities.py", line 124, in send_mail
    smtp.login('fu@gmail.com','fu')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 576, in login
    raise SMTPException("SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to send email (Gmail as mail provider) using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/trying-to-send-email-gmail-as-mail-provider-using-python)

Answer (score 28):

You need a call to `starttls()` before you login:

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
smtp.starttls()
smtp.login('fu@gmail.com', 'fu')
```

Also, your `send_from` should be a `str`, not a `list`:

```
send_from='fu@gmail.com'
```

Note that `smtp.starttls()` calls `smtp.ehlo()` implicitly:

> If there has been no previous EHLO or HELO command this session, this method tries ESMTP EHLO first. https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.starttls

Answer (score 2):

On gmail you also have to give a `smtp.ehlo()` before `smtp.starttls()`
This is also duplicate of [How to send an email with Gmail as provider using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python)