# Python doesn't send email: smtplib.SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server

Tags: python, email, localhost

I am trying to send email via Python but I am having an error.

This is my code:

```
import smtplib

content = 'example bla bla'
mail = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('from@example.com','password')
mail.sendmail('from@example.com','to@example.com',content)
mail.close()
```

When I run the file, this error shows up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SendEmail.py", line 11, in <module>
    mail.starttls()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 637, in starttls
    raise SMTPException("STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

There are posts about other people with the same problem but usually is just the order of the commands that is wrong (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765073/cant-send-email-via-python-using-gmail-smtplib-smtpexception-smtp-auth-extens)) and apparently mine is correct.

If I change `mail = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')` to `mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)` it works well. That makes me think that the problem may be in the configuration of the "localhost" but if I open `http://localhost` in the browser the page "It works" is presented so I think the localhost is well configured.

Does anyone know where can be the problem?

Comment: Opening `http://localhost` doesn't mean much in the context of email, since it uses `http` whereas email uses `smtp`. So, no, the local host is probably not properly configured, and the issue is that `STARTTLS` is not supported.

Comment: Well, thanks for the answer. I will try to configure smtp.

Answer (score 2):

Try commenting out `mail.starttls()`. i had this problem and it works in my code.

```
import smtplib
import string
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('mailrelay.address.com', 587) #email relay address
smtpObj.ehlo()
#smtpObj.starttls() #commented this out as was causing issues
smtpObj.login('domain\username', 'pwrd123')
```

Comment: Please note that this means that you're not encrypting the connection. I.e. both the credentials & emails are sent in plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to login to the SMTP server running on 'localhost' ('localhost' is conventionally the same computer your program is running on.)

Try this:

```
import smtplib

content = 'example bla bla'
mail = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
mail.ehlo()
mail.sendmail('from@example.com','to@example.com',content)
mail.close()
```