# How to make this work (Gmail Server Python Coding)?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's my code.

```
import smtplib
from Tkinter import *

def sendgmail(froma, toa, usern, passw, message):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
    server.starttls()
    server.login(username, password)
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, msg)
    server.quit()

maingui = Tk()
maingui.title('Gmail Sender')

fromaddrvar = StringVar()
toaddrvar = StringVar()
usernamevar = StringVar()
passwordvar = StringVar()
msgvar = StringVar()

fromaddre = Entry(maingui, textvariable=fromaddrvar).pack()
toaddre = Entry(maingui, textvariable=toaddrvar).pack()
usernamee = Entry(maingui, textvariable=usernamevar).pack()
passworde = Entry(maingui, textvariable=passwordvar).pack()
msge = Entry(maingui, textvariable=msgvar)

fromaddr = fromaddrvar.get()
toaddr = toaddrvar.get()
username = usernamevar.get()
password = passwordvar.get()
msg = msgvar.get()

inputbut = Button(text='send', command=sendgmail(fromaddr, toaddr, username, password, msg)).pack()
```

When I run the code, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Anand/Coding/Python/PyCharm Community Edition 3.0.1/Projects/Gmail Sender/Main.py", line 34, in <module>
    sendgmailcall = sendgmail(fromaddr, toaddr, username, password, msg)
  File "D:/Anand/Coding/Python/PyCharm Community Edition 3.0.1/Projects/Gmail Sender/Main.py", line 9, in sendgmail
    server.login(username, password)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 614, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 x4sm76670047eef.1 - gsmtp')
```

By the Way, I am running the code in Pycharm 3.0 . I am new to server and system programming.

Please help me by giving the solution and explaining it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to send email (Gmail as mail provider) using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/trying-to-send-email-gmail-as-mail-provider-using-python)

Answer (score 1):

Add `server.ehlo()` before `server.starttls()`.

Comment: I tried it out. But it is still not working. I think the problem is that the 'server' part runs before taking username and password input in tkinter. And so, authentication error takes place. Any ideas to avoid this?