# How to fix errors in establishing network with Gmail and how to make a email sender? - python

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, python-3.3

I am fairly new to python so I need lots of help with stuff :) I am having issues with this:

```
elif(command == "email" or command == "Email"):
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    euser = input("Enter Gmail Username: ")
    epass = input("Enter Gmail Password: ")
    server.login(euser, epass)
    msginput = input("Enter Message: ")
    msg = ("\n"+msginput)
    sourcemail = input("Enter Your Email: ")
    targetemail = input("Enter Your Recipient: ")
    server.sendmail(sourcemail, targetemail, msg)
```

All of this may be wrong. However, after I enter my gmail username and password, it gives this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/19austinh/Google Drive/Other/Python/Login.py", line 145, in <module>
    server.login(euser, epass)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/smtplib.py", line 595, in login
    raise SMTPException("SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

I don't know how to fix that. Also, is my script correct? If not, please tell me what to fix. Any answers are greatly appreciated :)

Edit:

Also, how do you make a subject input? So do I just add:

```
subjectinput = input("Enter Subject: ")
```

and

```
smtplib.subject = ("\n"+subjectinput)
```

or something? Because it does not send the email when I did that.

Comment: which Python you are using? 3, 2?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: look at the traceback. It says 3.3 in there.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/trying-to-send-email-gmail-as-mail-provider-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Gmail APIs documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview):

> **The outgoing SMTP server, smtp.gmail.com, requires TLS**. Use port 465,
>   or port 587 if your client begins with plain text before issuing the
>   `STARTTLS` command.

Call `starttls` before `login`:

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtp.starttls() # <---------
smtp.login(username, password)
```

Comment: Cool! Works! Then how do you make a subject input?

Comment: @HelloWorld, You need to add `Subject` header. (Header lines and body are separated by a blank line)  For example: `smtp.sendmail(sender, recipient, 'Subject: title\r\n\r\nbody of the mail')`

Comment: so do I add: "subjectinput = input("Enter Subject: ")" and "smtplib.subject = ("\n"+subjectinput)" or something? Because it does not send the email.

Comment: @HelloWorld, `subjectinput = input("Enter Subject: ")` and `server.sendmail(sourcemail, targetmail, 'Subject: {}\r\n\r\n{}'.format(subjectinput, msg))`