# Trying to send email from python

Tags: python, email, smtp

i am new to python, when am trying to sending mail by using python  my program is bellow

```
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTP

sender = 'raju.ab@gmail.com'
receivers = ['sudeer.p@eunoia.in']

message = """ this message sending from python
for testing purpose
"""

try:
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.login(username,password)
smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
smtpObj.quit()
print "Successfully sent email"
except smtplib.SMTPException:
```

print "Error: unable to send email"

when i execute it shows Error: unable to send mail message, how to send email in python please explain

Comment: *"it shows Error: unable to send mail message"* - that's exactly what you've asked it to do! If you didn't wrap the whole process in a `try`, you would get a more specific error message that gave you more information about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i have done in code :

1.Added a error object to get the error message

```
import smtplib
from smtplib import SMTP       

try:
    sender = 'xxx@gmail.com'
    receivers = ['xxx.com']

    message = """ this message sending from python
    for testing purpose
    """
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587)
    smtpObj.ehlo()
    smtpObj.starttls()
    smtpObj.ehlo()
    smtpObj.login('xxx','xxx')
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
    smtpObj.quit()
    print "Successfully sent email"
except smtplib.SMTPException,error:
    print str(error)
    print "Error: unable to send email"
```

If u ran this code u would see a error message like this stating  that google is not allowing u to login via code

Things to change in gmail:

1.Login to gmail

2.Go to this link  https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

3.Click enable then retry the code

Hopes it help :)

But there are security threats if u enable it

Comment: I get invalid syntax at except line, pointing at the comma before error (line 20 in your code). Why?

Comment: @YannisDran are you using python 3

Comment: @YannisDran could you show the sample code and except syntax is different in python 3

Comment: as soon as I go home, I ll post it to you.

Comment: For Python 2.6 and later and Python 3.x:
except Exception as e: print(e)

Answer (score 2):

as is said here: [How to send an email with Gmail as provider using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/trying-to-send-email-gmail-as-mail-provider-using-python)

This code works. But GMAIL wil warn you if you want to allow this script send the email or not. Sign in in your account, and accesss this URL:  https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

```
import smtplib
gmail_user = "yourmail@gmail.com"
gmail_pwd = "mypassword"
FROM = 'yourmail@gmail.com'
TO = ['receiber@email.com'] #must be a list
SUBJECT = "Testing sending using gmail"
TEXT = "Testing sending mail using gmail servers"
# Prepare actual message
message = """\From: %s\nTo: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)
try:
  #server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER) 
  server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) #or port 465 doesn't seem to work!
  server.ehlo()
  server.starttls()
  server.login(gmail_user, gmail_pwd)
  server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
  #server.quit()
  server.close()
  print 'successfully sent the mail'
except:
  print "failed to send mail"
```

Comment: Thanks for the information about the warning. The URL information worked for me.