# Python SMTP error: "(10013, 'Permission denied')"

Tags: python, email, smtp, host

So I have this Python send-email file that sends an email (the text from a file) to a recipient specified inside the code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
msgContent = open(Sourcefilelocation, "rb")
msg = MIMEText(spam.read())
msgContent.close()
msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
msg['From'] = FROM_CLIENT_EMAIL
msg['To'] = TO_CLIENT_EMAIL
#THE ERROR BELOW
s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
```

I understand that there is no mail server on localhost, but how do I make a mail server on that and if I can't then why does `s = smtplib.SMTP('gmail.com')` take so long if it even works? What do I need to make it work? Any help is appreciated.

```
output: >> Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#24>", line 1, in <module>
  s = smtplib.SMTP('gmail.com')
File "C:\Python25\lib\smtplib.py", line 244, in __init__
  (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
File "C:\Python25\lib\smtplib.py", line 310, in connect
  raise socket.error, msg
error: (10013, 'Permission denied')
```

And the gmail smtp code takes too long.

Comment: Any chance you got a virusscanner that is blocking the socket connection?

Comment: yes i have no good virus thing

Comment: sadly.... and @DJanssens

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10147497/2526441 it seems to also add a port number.