# Getting error to email through python script

Tags: python

I am very new to python. I was trying to send a mail using a python script. But getting the below mentioned error:

```
$ python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    server.login("rake.son25@gmail.com", "*********")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 622, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, '5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvm\n5.7.14 7HCHLzWCRCqEWA7MrN_ugeXO84BVMOFJ0g1E6_G7PGiHJmzxMOLKwsWe8s1STDSdnu62FE\n5.7.14 kiIxlsG8SNxbLi6J9ldrBZZlGEq7iQwdu_jyiZqCBnbaMilPIb8h0n8qbQ-qIlgqkBwb8n\n5.7.14 Fu3wlNDH2Eb8nSYcTEZgZT7o-LS_tdj393kLlex2GILGCcy7McM6r72Ml1u7Dl-fc7hWjM\n5.7.14 int0yILB5Ab1MYcNt8uigK2ZyemJU> Please log in via your web browser and\n5.7.14 then try again.\n5.7.14  Learn more at\n5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 fj19sm61312778pab.37 - gsmtp')
```

But I mentioned the correct pw and email in the script. 
main.py:

```
import smtplib
msg = "YOUR MESSAGE!"
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.googlemail.com')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login("rake.son25@gmail.com", "mypassword")    
server.sendmail("rake.son25@gmail.com", "rakeshlochansarma25@gmail.com",msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: Please have a look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the configuration is correct? I think Gmail SMTP is smtp.gmail.com. And try to add the port:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

If it still doesn't work, Google is probably blocking your app. For more information see [this link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it following below steps:

Go to Google's Account Security Settings: www.google.com/settings/security

Find the field "Access for less secure apps". Set it to "Allowed".