# python requests - login to gmail fails

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, requests
import lxml.html
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'}
form_data = {}
url = 'https://accounts.google.com/Login'
login = requests.get(url)
html = lxml.html.fromstring ( login.text )
data = html.xpath('//input[@type="hidden"]')

for x in data:
    name = x.get('name')
    value = x.get('value')
    form_data[name] = value

form_data['Email'] = 'my email here'
form_data['Passwd'] = 'my password here'
print(form_data)

with requests.session() as s:
    response = requests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=headers)
    req = requests.get('https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox')

    print(req.text)
    print ( 'inbakke' in req )
```

I tried making a script that would request a login with post. But it doesnt work. When I look at the "req.text" html at the end. It seems like I am still on the submit your passwd and email page. 
https://gyazo.com/2db56030077c2e9a73154de0ab9f801c - the "req.text"

The form_data I am sending is the following:

`{'_utf8': '☃', 'Email': 'MY EMAIL', 'SessionState': '', 'bgresponse': 'js_disabled', 'GALX': '0vyTLpgavJc', 'ProfileInformation': '', 'gxf': 'AFoagUXHK7rZNkBVVIUkhqVxSRX27RFOLg:1482790613384', 'Page': 'PasswordSeparationSignIn', 'Passwd': 'MY PASSOWRD'}`

Can some smart person please explain what went wrong, and how I should fix it?

Comment: this isn't a documented authentication/email-pulling workflow and it it unfaithful to what goes on with a browsers.  pycurl might claim to pull gmail.

with browser type workflow, 'requests.get' would be reusing session data in 'response'.

Comment: I am sorry @MarcCondon I didn't get that, what is the problem?

Comment: use `smtplib` or `imaplib` to work with email. ie. [how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python)

Comment: I am not trying to send an email, im trying to log into gmail. Not just gmail, but any other website for that sake. 

Can smtplib or imaplib help me with that?

Comment: If you are trying to log into email servers, then yes `smtplib` will work but it can't help you to log into web applications.

Comment: for your question, just make sure those are the only fields being posted while login. I observed one more field `{'signIn':'Sign in'}` while I try to login.