# How to send mail to selected mailbox on Gmail?

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, gmail, imap

I want to send mail into selected mailbox(mail folder, Gmail's label) on a gmail account.

Actually, I made a function which is getting emails on selected mailbox through IMAP Protocol. But, now I have to make a function which sends emails into my selected mailbox.

How can i selectively send mail to this mailbox?

Comment: your question is not clear. Is the difference between what you have been able to do and what you want to do, that earlier it was using IMAP and now you want to do it using python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send an email with Gmail as provider using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python)

Comment: @user1993 Hummm....  That mean I want to send mail into selected mailbox on gmail using python3. "mailbox" seems like gmail's label.

Comment: @Ohjeah  Actually, I saw that. But That is not mention about selected mailbox(label or mail folder)...

Comment: @user1993 and Billal BEGUERADJ, thanks to your fixing my grammer

Comment: Have you looked at the `APPEND` command?

Comment: No....? What is it ??. Could you tell me more? @Max

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-append.php

Comment: That's perfectly right!!!!!! If you write answer about this question, I will select your answer. That's keyword help to me !