# sending mail from python in 2018

Tags: python-3.x, email

I know there are a lots of how to send mail questions before, but does sending mail from python scripts not work anymore? I've tried to use the SMTP lib with the following script:

```
import smtplib
fromaddr = 'mymail@gmail.com'
toaddr = 'someones@gmail.com'
msg = "\r\n".join([
    "From: mymail@gmail.com",
    "To: someonesmail@gmail.com",
    "Subject: Just a message",
    "",    
    'Why, oh why?'
    ])

username = 'mymail@gmail.com'
pwd = 'mypassword'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username, pwd)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

But it says to login via a web browser, and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python) says that google now uses an api to send mails. So, having confusion about the possibility to send mails via scripts without using any of google's api, Is it possible?