# Sending An Email To Myself With Python

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email from a mail.com account to the same mail.com account with this code:

```
import smtplib
USER = "EMAIL@MAIL.COM"
PASS = "PASSWORD"
data = "TEST 123"
s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.com',587)
s.login(USER, PASS)
s.sendmail(USER, USER,data)
s.quit()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1051)
```

All I need to do is send an email from either `gmail.com`, `mail.com` or `outlook.com`; I'm trying to send either a text file or just a body of text.

I've  tried many solutions from other posts but could not get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's because you are using `smtplib.SMTP_SSL` and using port `587`. Try changing the port to `465`. Then it should work.

Learn more about it, [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html). And here's a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147455/how-to-send-an-email-with-gmail-as-provider-using-python) for reference.